# std::vector::resize(size_type) requires CopyInsertable?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

This question is made while I answer [this another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30935840/does-the-c-standard-specify-stl-implementation-details-for-the-compiler).

[N3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) 23.3.6.3 "vector capacity" says (it's in 770 page):

> void resize(size_type sz);
>
> Eﬀects: If `sz <= size()`, equivalent to `erase(begin() + sz, end());`. If `size() < sz`, appends
>   `sz - size()` value-initialized elements to the sequence.
>
> Requires: T shall be CopyInsertable into *this.

However, [clang++ says it's okay though T is not copyable.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ada7ceb3f4d3868b) And I think it makes sense that `resize(size_type)` requires only destroyable/moveable/default constructable. It destroys if `sz <= size`, appends (which uses default constructing, and destroying and moving if the capacity is not enough) if `size() < sz`.

What is truth? Is it a standard defect? Or is it a mistake of both clang++ and me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are correct. It was a defect in C++11 that was fixed for C++14 by http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-defects.html#2033

The current wording says:

> Effects: If `sz < size()`, erases the last `size() - sz` elements from the sequence. Otherwise, appends
>   `sz - size()` default-inserted elements to the sequence.
>
> Requires: `T` shall be `MoveInsertable` and `DefaultInsertable` into `*this`.

The requirement on `Destructible` is in Table 95 and applies to all operations on all containers, not just `resize()`.

Comment: In the C++14 standard?

Comment: Then, in c++11, is it just standard defeat?

Comment: @PeterSchneider, yes, in C++14, and the latest working draft. It was a defect in C++11.