# What do the following phrases mean in C++: zero-, default- and value-initialization?

Tags: c++, initialization, c++-faq

What do the following phrases mean in C++:

- zero-initialization,
- default-initialization, and
- value-initialization

What should a C++ developer know about them?

Comment: This is related to (but not identical to) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/620137/do-the-parentheses-after-the-type-name-make-a-difference-with-new

Comment: There's more! The complete list of initializations: Value, direct, copy, list (C++11 new intro), aggregate, reference, zero, constant and default; http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization lists all of them with examples :)

Comment: @legends2k This is good, thank you! I was hoping somebody would talk about newer standards!

Answer (score 67, accepted):

One thing to realize is that 'value-initialization' is new with the C++ 2003 standard - it doesn't exist in the original 1998 standard (I think it might be the only difference that's more than a clarification).  See [Kirill V. Lyadvinsky's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1613341/what-do-the-following-phrases-mean-in-c-zero-default-and-value-initializati/1613383#1613383) for the definitions straight from the standard.

See this previous answer about the behavior of `operator new` for details on the the different behavior of these type of initialization and when they kick in (and when they differ from c++98 to C++03):

- [Do the parentheses after the type name make a difference with new?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620137/syntax-of-new/620402#620402)

The main point of the answer is:

> Sometimes the memory returned by the new operator will be initialized, and sometimes it won't depending on whether the type you're newing up is a POD, or if it's a class that contains POD members and is using a compiler-generated default constructor.
>
> - In C++1998 there are 2 types of initialization: zero and default
> - In C++2003 a 3rd type of initialization, value initialization was added.

To say they least, it's rather complex and when the different methods kick in are subtle.

One thing to certainly be aware of is that MSVC follows the C++98 rules, even in VS 2008 (VC 9 or cl.exe version 15.x).

The following snippet shows that MSVC and Digital Mars follow C++98 rules, while GCC 3.4.5 and Comeau follow the C++03 rules:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <new>

struct A { int m; }; // POD
struct B { ~B(); int m; }; // non-POD, compiler generated default ctor
struct C { C() : m() {}; ~C(); int m; }; // non-POD, default-initialising m

int main()
{
    char buf[sizeof(B)];
    std::memset( buf, 0x5a, sizeof( buf));

    // use placement new on the memset'ed buffer to make sure 
    //  if we see a zero result it's due to an explicit 
    //  value initialization
    B* pB = new(buf) B();   //C++98 rules - pB->m is uninitialized
                            //C++03 rules - pB->m is set to 0
    std::printf( "m  is %d\n", pB->m);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not that it matters for `int`, but `m()` on the third line value initializes m. Important if you change `int m;` to `B m;`. :)

Comment: Right - `A` and `C` aren't used in this example (they're carried over from the other linked answer). Even though C++98 and C++03 use different terminology when describing how `A` and `C` are constructed, the result is the same in both standards. Only `struct B` results in different behavior.

Comment: what i meant is that if you change C to `struct C { C() : m() {}; ~C(); B m; };`, then you will have `m.m` be 0. But if it would default-initialise `m` like you say C++03 does, then `m.m` would be not initialized like in C++98.

Comment: Additional interesting comments on MSVC handling of this feature: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3931312/value-initialization-and-non-pod-types/3931589#3931589

Comment: Which initialization takes place when you declare your type as a local variable, i.e. at the stack?

Comment: Here's a great reference on [`value-initialization`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) and [`default-initialization`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization).

Comment: g++ 4.4.7 20120313 for Red Hat 4.4.7-18 initializes m to 0 with your example (compiling with -std=c++98).

Comment: g++ 10.2.0 for Ubuntu initializes m to 0 with your example (compiling with -std=c++98) as well

Answer (score 91):

C++03 Standard 8.5/5:

> To ***zero-initialize*** an object of type T means:
>   — if T is a scalar type (3.9), the object is set to the value of 0 (zero) converted to T;
>   — if T is a non-union class type, each nonstatic data member and each base-class subobject is zero-initialized;
>   — if T is a union type, the object’s first named data member is zero-initialized;
>   — if T is an array type, each element is zero-initialized;
>   — if T is a reference type, no initialization is performed.
>
> To ***default-initialize*** an object of type T means:
>   — if T is a non-POD class type (clause 9), the default constructor for T is called (and the initialization is ill-formed if T has no accessible default constructor);
>   — if T is an array type, each element is default-initialized;
>   —  otherwise, the object is zero-initialized.
>
> To ***value-initialize*** an object of type T means:
>   — if T is a class type (clause 9) with a user-declared constructor (12.1), then the default constructor for T is called (and the initialization is ill-formed if T has no accessible default constructor);
>   — if T is a non-union class type without a user-declared constructor, then every non-static data member and base-class component of T is value-initialized;
>   — if T is an array type, then each element is value-initialized;
>   —  otherwise, the object is zero-initialized
>
> A program that calls for default-initialization or value-initialization of an entity of reference type is ill-formed. If T is a cv-qualified type, the cv-unqualified version of T is used for these definitions of zero-initialization, default-initialization, and value-initialization.

Comment: This might be outdated for C++11. [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization) states that default initialization _does not_ zero-initialize members (only value initialization does).

Comment: @android raises an important point, which I don't see answered elsewhere, so I've made a new question.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22233148/meaning-of-default-initialization-changed-in-c11

Comment: Exactly zero-intialization in case of default-initialization does not happen. 
Value remains indeterminate.