# How can I make `new[]` default-initialize the array of primitive types?

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization

Every now and then I need to call `new[]` for built-in types (usually `char`). The result is an array with uninitialized values and I have to use `memset()` or `std::fill()` to initialize the elements.

How do I make `new[]` default-initialize the elements?

Comment: I am not sure whether this is valid, but works fine on VC9. `int* p = new int[10]();`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to initialise memory with new operator in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204176/how-to-initialise-memory-with-new-operator-in-c)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`int* p = new int[10]()` should do.

However, as [Michael points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2468203/how-can-i-make-new-default-initialize-the-array-of-primitive-types/2468221#2468221), using `std::vector` would be better.

Comment: You can also the c++11 uniform initialization syntax: `new int[10]{}`.

Comment: @Fernando: You can now, thanks for pointing this out. You'd have had a hard time finding a compiler that accepted that in May 2010, though. `:)`

Answer (score 25):

Why don't you just use std::vector? It will do that for you, automatically.

```
std::vector<int> x(100); // 100 ints with value 0
std::vector<int> y(100,5); // 100 ints with value 5
```

It is also important to note that using vectors is better, since the data will be reliably destructed. If you have a `new[]` statement, and then an exception is subsequently thrown, the allocated data will be leaked. If you use an std::vector, then the vector's destructor will be invoked, causing the data to be properly deallocated.

Comment: I totally agree that vector is often better, but still I want new[]. +1 anyway.

Answer (score 4):

This relatively old topic can now be enhanced by another variant.
I was using bool, because there is a quite strange specialization for `vector<bool>`

```
#include <memory>
...
unique_ptr<bool[]> p{ new bool[count] {false} };
```

this can now be accessed with the `operator[]`

```
p[0] = true;
```

just like `std::vector<T>` this is exception safe.

(I suppose this wasn't possible back at 2010 :) )

Answer (score 1):

Primitive type default initialization example:

```
int* p = new int[5];          // gv gv gv gv gv (gv - garbage value)
int* p = new int[5]();        // 0  0  0  0  0 
int* p = new int[5]{};        // 0  0  0  0  0  (Modern C++)
int* p = new int[5]{ 1,2,3 }; // 1  2  3  0  0  (Modern C++)
```