# Does new[] call default constructor in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, standards, new-operator

When I use new[] to create an array of my classes:

```
int count = 10;
A *arr = new A[count];
```

I see that it calls a default constructor of `A` `count` times. As a result `arr` has `count` initialized objects of type `A`.
But if I use the same thing to construct an int array:

```
int *arr2 = new int[count];
```

it is not initialized. All values are something like `-842150451` though default constructor of int assignes its value to `0`.

Why is there so different behavior? Does a default constructor not called only for built-in types?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make \`new\[\]\` default-initialize the array of primitive types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2468203/how-can-i-make-new-default-initialize-the-array-of-primitive-types)

Answer (score 74, accepted):

See [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2468203/how-can-i-make-new-default-initialize-the-array-of-primitive-types/2468254#2468254) to [a very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2468203/how-can-i-make-new-default-initialize-the-array-of-primitive-types). When you use `new[]` each element is initialized by the default constructor except when the type is a built-in type. Built-in types are left unitialized by default.

To have built-in type array default-initialized use

```
new int[size]();
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't actually know you could add the braces to default initialize built-in types. I've been working with C++ for years. That's either exciting or very sad!

Answer (score 4):

Built-in types don't have a default constructor even though they can in some cases receive a default value.

But in your case, `new` just allocates enough space in memory to store `count` `int` objects, ie. it allocates `sizeof<int>*count`.

Comment: @rubber boots: `int i ();` does not initialize a varaible named `i`. It declares a function `i` returning an int. You may have meant `int i = int();`

Comment: @James: In C++0x you can finally say what you mean: `int x{};` :)

Comment: @James, oops - wtf did I write? Thanks for clearing this up. Wrong deduction from `int *i = new int();`. @Cerdic, Sorry for Posting BS.

Answer (score 2):

Primitive type default initialization could be done by below forms:

```
    int* x = new int[5];          // gv gv gv gv gv (gv - garbage value)
    int* x = new int[5]();        // 0  0  0  0  0 
    int* x = new int[5]{};        // 0  0  0  0  0  (Modern C++)
    int* x = new int[5]{1,2,3};   // 1  2  3  0  0  (Modern C++)
```

Answer (score 0):

`int` is not a class, it's a built in data type, therefore no constructor is called for it.