# Segmentation fault when assigning vector with another vector using MATLAB mex

Tags: c++, matlab, vector, segmentation-fault, mex

This is where the bug would appear during execution:

```
C[check].S = vector<int>(S1);
```

end C is a global struct array and is defined as:

```
typedef struct C_type{
    double e;
    vector <int> S;
}Cache;
Cache *C;
```

Now this problem is sometimes it get segmentation fault error, so any hint to fix that? (`S1` is not empty and `S[check].S` is always empty).

Comment: You can't just declare a pointer and expect it to create the actual object...  `new`.

Comment: Hi, I initialize the cache with C = (Cache *)malloc(sizeof(Cache)*K*T*T);

Comment: @chappjc so I should initailize each element with new? Thanks

Comment: Since this is C++, I'd use `Cache *C = new Cache[K*T*T];` (don't forget to `delete[] C` when you're done with it.  The `vector<int> S` needs to be initialized when each `Cache` is created, so I'd [use `new`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3575458/does-new-call-default-constructor-in-c).  Also have a look at this post on [`struct` in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/q/612328/2778484), which might simplify your struct definition by getting rid of the `typedef`.

Comment: Thanks, I used to use malloc() and free(), I guess the reason is malloc didn't consider the dynammic memory consume inside each element so there might be the issue. Now I am changing back to new() and delete [] C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is C++, use `Cache *C = new Cache[K*T*T];`. The `vector<int> S` needs to be initialized when each `Cache` is created, so [use `new` to accomplish this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3575458/does-new-call-default-constructor-in-c). The only thing `malloc` does, is allocate chunks of bytes, but does not initialize the contents.

Don't forget to `delete[] C` when you're done with it.

Also have a look at [this post on `struct` in C++,](https://stackoverflow.com/q/612328/2778484) which might simplify your struct definition by getting rid of the `typedef`.

Comment: @Coderzelf I'm glad it helped.  Once important thing about `new` is  that each element will have it's constructor run.  In this case, it simply initializes each member (non-trivial for the vector member).  Feel free to vote up too if you want! :)