# Can sizeof of struct be affected by array metadata?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, struct

There has been a number of questions regarding the `sizeof` of `struct`'s (not) being equal to the sum of `sizeof`'s of its elements. Usually this is due to data alignment. This question is *not* concerned with data alignment, so please suppose that sizes of all types are multiples of the alignment (say 4B).

As explained [here](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/freestore-mgmt#num-elems-in-new-array), allocating an array will result in some metadata beeing stored about the size of the allocated array. Let's say we had the following code:

```
const int size = 10;

struct X {
    int someInt;
    int array[size];
};

struct Y {
    int someInt;
    T array[size];
};
```

Since the `size` is known at compile-time, the compiler *should* be smart enough to determine that there is no need to store any metadata in the case of `X`. The compiler *could* be smart enough to follow this reasoning even in the case of `Y` (there could be difference between C and C++ here, since in C++ there is the additional requirement of calling destructors for individual instances of `T`).

My question is: am I *guaranteed* that `sizeof(X) == (size + 1) * sizeof(int)` or is it compiler-specific? Or more generally, is `sizeof(Y) == size * sizeof(T) + sizeof(int)`?

---

**EDIT:** To hopefully clarify things a bit: the question is about *both* C and C++. Also the original motivation for asking this question is this. If I run

```
X *foo = new X[100];
```

or it's C equivalent somewhere in code, will it create a *continuous* block of memory of size `100 * (size + 1) * sizeof(int)`?

Comment: You aren't "allocating" any arrays in a way that would necessitate any meta-data.

Comment: There is no *metadata*. These are arrays and not std::vectors.

Comment: Your link explanation is for dynamic allocation, there is no metadata in your case.

Comment: The text in your link is talking about dynamic allocation with `new []`.

Comment: C: Tossing aside alignment/packing issues.  `sizeof(Y) == size * sizeof(T) + sizeof(int)` is true.  If some form of _mettadata_ existed, it would not contribute to the `sizeof` nor would it exist between  `someInt` and `array`.  Yet _why_ is this important?  What is code attempting that relies on this feature?

Comment: Arrays are constructs with constant size fixed at compile time - why would there be a need for any metadata? Sure, during compilation the *compiler* probably keeps some metadata around, but in the final binary it's just a chunk of memory with no metadata needed since the compiler will have already resolved any accesses into it into fixed values.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya C implementation commonly uses metadata to manage the memory space.  Lots of object files embed metadata for debugging purposes.  C specifies more of what is and not what is not.  The point is that the meta data is not available in standard C code.  C does specify the contiguousness of objects which seems to be OP's concern.  IOW, does OP's yet to be stated need for contiguousness, get messed up by potential metadata?

Comment: @chux I see, OP means the implementation metadata and not something in the language. That as you mentioned won't interfere with the struct packing since C enforces how structs need to be packed. Also most implementation metadata (like md for heap allocated chunks) would always be out of bounds of the accessible memory and in general should not interfere with any data structures, be it structs or arrays or anything else.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya Agreed.  Access to some MD like [`malloc_usable_size`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc_usable_size) is certainly implementation defined.

Comment: @chux I think I was incorrect in saying *C enforces how structs need to be packed*. I recall that is implementation defined. So in theory it is possible that there is some field md is stored. But in practice I am sure no compiler would do that.

Comment: `X *foo = new X[100];` might/might not create "a continuous block of memory of size `100 * (size + 1) * sizeof(int)`". Very likely yes, but it depends on things.  Knowing why this is important to code may help.

Comment: @chux Basically I have an array of `int`s that can be thought to be partitioned into smaller chunks. Something like treating array of `m * n` elements as representation of a `m x n` matrix. What I wanted to know is whether I can create an "alias" for these chunks and allocate an array of those without loosing control over memory (alignment, ...). I asked more out of curiosity, to know C, C++ better. Nothing serious depends on this.

Comment: @insert_name_here How does knowing if `int someInt` and `int array[size];` are packed next to each other relate to your [`m*n` goal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43216468/can-sizeof-of-struct-be-affected-by-array-metadata?noredirect=1#comment73566679_43216468)?

Comment: @chux If they weren't (there was some "metadata" containing size of `array` between them or whatever), then there wouldn't be "just consecutive <number> of ints" in memory, but rather that plus some stuff in between. Therefore the allocated memory wouldn't be **identical** and it wouldn't be just an "*alias*" for the same underlying structure. If so, you can't use this approach (and save yourself from calculating a bunch of offsets) without (possibly) changing how the data is stored in memory.

Comment: @insert_name_here Sounds like you agree with the limitation of the posted code as commented [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43216468/can-sizeof-of-struct-be-affected-by-array-metadata?noredirect=1#comment73543243_43216468).  The "... save yourself from calculating a bunch of offsets" is amiss as it supposes that the alternative to the posted approach is tedious.  As with many problems. clearly identifying the coding goals, rather than assessing the pros/cons of a single candidate approach, is useful at getting a better answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C arrays in common implementations don't store any metadata around them, however, padding may be added to structs so that `a_struct_ptr + 1` has sufficient alignment for `a_struct`.

In the case of the first struct (`{ int someInt; int array[size]; }`), no padding should be required, so

```
sizeof(X) == (size + 1) * sizeof(int)
```

should hold (though, I don't think compilers are obligated to guarantee it).

In the case of the second struct, the alignment requirements of `T` and `int` may cause padding to be added to the struct, which would invalidate your equation.

Comment: "C arrays don't store any metadata" Hmmm.  Certainly C does not specify any metadata.  A compiler could store meta-data in some fashion though with each object.  The issue is: is such added data allowed to be between members of a `struct`?  IMO: no.

Comment: I think that's an empirical observation that compilers "don't store metadata".  If they did, it would be associated with the type rather than variables of the type — a bit like v-tables in C++.  At most, there might be a pointer to somewhere in the tail of the structure in compiler-applied padding.  But it is pretty unlikely to be an actual problem.  Yes, in theory, a compiler could add information into a structure.  No, in practice, compilers don't do it because there's no need/benefit.

Comment: Padding can very well be added for e.g 64 bit alignment or even wider cache-line alignment.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler  Hmm, I suppose if a compiler wanted to add some MD between structure members, it could make `max_align_t` very wide and hide it in padding, except for adjacent `max_align_t` members.  Still, unclear why this is important to OP.

Comment: I have a feeling, OP was referring to metadata which is part of the language. This is because he writes that it should not be there because size of the array is known. And also understands that some things can be compiler specific (last line of the question). And the fact that he asks if this is compile specific clearly implies he is not talking about implementation specific md. I think we are reading too much into the question.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya I suspect you are correct, yet OP has been silent since posting about 1 hour ago.

Comment: @chux I have edited the question to try to clarify things. Sorry for not communicating, this is my first SO question and I always lived under the impression that response time is in span of days, not minutes. As noted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3575458/does-new-call-default-constructor-in-c), array initialization in C++ calls constructor for non-primitive types. Therefore I would *assume*, that there has to be some "metadata" to indicate the number of times destructor is called for array members when leaving the scope.

Comment: @insert_name_here If a type needs to keep track of the number of times a destructor is called, the type needs record that as its own data.  Code will only call the destructor once, by C++ design, unless code has additional explicit destructor calls.

Comment: @chux can I interpret it in the way that compiler will provide destructor `~Y()` where it will call destructors in a for loop for every instance of `T` inside of `Y`?

Comment: @PSkocik thank you. Could you possibly include some thoughts on the editted part of the question in your answer or in here?

Comment: @insert_name_here Arrays are guaranteed to be contiguous. `new X[100];` will allocate a contiguous block of X, size = sizeof(X)*100, initialized with the X::X() ctor, if it exists.  The dtors (if any) will be run upon `delete []foo;`.

Comment: @PSkocik So if I make an array of `100 * sizeof(int) * (size + 1)` ints or `100` `X`s, the allocated memory will be completely identical? (Sorry, last question.)

Comment: As I said in my answer, it's very likely that `struct X` will be sized `sizeof(int)*(size+1)`. Sane compilers won't pad it. It's conceivable, though, that an insane and still conformant compiler would pad it. I don't think the standard prohibits compilers from adding arbitrary padding.

Answer (score 0):

Meta data can hide between `struct` members.  I have never see this use for meta-data, yet a compiler could play with the alignments of types, up to a point, to provide a discontinuous memory between two `int` members by obliging the alignment of an `int` to be greater than an `int` width such as 4 bytes.  If the compiler uses this for meta-data, performance padding or spite, it is irrelevant.  The point is that it may exist.

C99/C11 provides `max_align_t`, so types will not natively exceed that alignment per the C spec.

> A *fundamental alignment* is represented by an alignment less than or equal to the greatest alignment supported by the implementation in all contexts, which is equal to `_Alignof (max_align_t)`.  §6.2.811dr §6.2.8 2
>
> `max_align_t` which is an object type whose alignment is as great as is supported by the implementation in all contexts; §7.19 2

So any structure member that is smaller than `max_align_t` is subject to padding/meta data *in a potential context*.