# c++ initial value of dynamic array

Tags: c++

I need to dynamically create an array of integer. I've found that when using a static array the syntax

```
int a [5]={0};
```

initializes correctly the value of all elements to 0.

Is there a way to do something similar when creating a dynamic array like

```
int* a = new int[size];
```

without having to loop over all elements of the a array? or maybe assigning the value with a for loop is still the optimal way to go?
Thanks

Comment: Can't you use a `std::vector`? This would initialise all values to zero (or any other value you choose)

Comment: See the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546620/operator-new-initializes-memory-to-zero

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make \`new\[\]\` default-initialize the array of primitive types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2468203/how-can-i-make-new-default-initialize-the-array-of-primitive-types)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Sure, just use `()` for value-initialization:

```
 int* ptr = new int[size]();
```

(taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2468254/57428) to my earlier closely related question)

Comment: @shartptooth I tried that and get an error: error: ISO C++ forbids initialization in array new [-fpermissive]

Comment: @Arno that should compile. What compiler are you using?

Comment: @juanchopanza GCC g++ compiler within eclipse cdt

Comment: @Arno maybe it is an old version. I have no problem with 4.6 or 4.7.

Comment: @juanchopanza i'm running g++ 4.6.2. Maybe it's linked to the -fpermissive warning?

Comment: Fixed. I tried to put a value within the bracket and that's not working as expected. Anyway, problem solved!

Comment: @Arno not for me, fine with 4.6.1 and -fpermissive. Even with -pedantic-errors.

Comment: I am getting error if I try to provide some value say 5.  int* ptr = new int[4](5);

Comment: @CppLearner That is intended. You can only initialize with `()` to zero. There is no way to initialize all instances to a value different then the default-value.

Comment: @CppLearner: you seem to be looking for [`std::uninitialized_fill`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/uninitialized_fill)

Comment: @Matthieu M : Thanks for your inputs. Actually I was wondering if I can initialize dynamic array elements to some user specified value,say 5, using the single statement int *ptr = new int[4](5); //trying to initialize dynamic array of 4 elements with value 5. But itseems like,as pointed out by RedX that it is not possible.

Comment: @CppLearner: Indeed it is not. For array you need to first allocate the storage and then initialize/assign the values you want. There are several STL algorithms designed for this. `uninitialized_fill` deals with raw storage and `copy` and `generate` allow to assign to existing objects. One more reason to have dirt-cheap default construction.

Comment: @sharptooth What about simple structures, say `stuct Point{int x; int y;};`?

Answer (score 6):

I'd do:

```
int* a = new int[size];
memset(a, 0, size*sizeof(int));
```

Comment: @Arno The proper way is sharptooth's answer.

Comment: 'without having to loop over all elements of the a array' - Isn't that effectively what you're doing with `memset`? Albeit that memset will no doubt be machine optimised.

Comment: @Component10: Yes, it will most certainly be optimised. But I agree with Luchian, the proper answer is sharptooth's. Bear in mind thought that even with that syntactically proper solution, the "memset" will be done "under the hood".

Comment: With GCC, the `memset` will generate a warning for non-[trivial](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivial) types. Here, the `int` is trivial, so it works. For other types, that may have a non-default constructor, or default initialized fields, this will produce a warning, with a suggestion to use value initialization.

Answer (score 5):

I'd advise you to use `std::vector<int>` or `std::array<int,5>`

Answer (score 4):

Value initialize the elements with `()`

Example:

```
int *p = new int[10];       // block of ten uninitialized ints
int *p2 = new int[10]();    // block of ten ints value initialized to 0
```

Answer (score 3):

To initialize with other values than 0,

for pointer array:

```
int size = 10;
int initVal = 47;
int *ptrArr = new int[size];
std::fill_n(ptrArr, size, initVal);
std::cout << *(ptrArr + 4) << std::endl;
std::cout << ptrArr[4] << std::endl;
```

For non pointer array

```
int size = 10;
int initVal = 47;
int arr[size];
std::fill_n(arr, size, initVal);
```

Works pretty Much for any DataType!

!Be careful, some compilers might not complain accessing a value out of the range of the array which might return a non-zero value

Answer (score 0):

```
int *a=new int[n];
memset(a, 0, n*sizeof(int));
```

That sets the all the bytes of the array to 0. For `char *` too, you could use memset.
See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/memset/ for a more formal definition and usage.