# Static global variables in C++

Tags: c++, variables, pointers, static, global

I would like to make an array of integers via the malloc method. I want this array to be global and be used anywhere in my  program. I put code in a header file that looked like this:

```
static int *pieces;
```

Then I have a function that fills it with numbers that I want in there. The function is in a namespace and the namespace is implemented in its own .cpp file. However, I import the header file into main.c and call the function from the namespace that creates the array like:

```
pieces = malloc(sizeof(int) * 128);
```

But when I try to access numbers in the array in main (after calling the function that creates my array), it crashes and says that pieces wasn't initialized. But in the function I have I can create it and manipulate the numbers in it just fine. I was under the impression that by making pieces a static variable, whenever some function anywhere changes (or sets it) then that will affect the usage of the variable anywhere. Basically what I'm trying to say is why does pieces appear unset in main, even though I set it in a function that I called?

Comment: Why would you like to use `malloc` in C++?

Comment: Remove the word `static` because that makes a local copy in each file.

Comment: @Oli what else would I use?

Comment: @ChristianDaley: `new`.  Or better yet, a `std::vector`.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey: Simply removing `static` will lead to multiple-definition errors.

Comment: @ChristianDaley [Read this please](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Comment: @Oli: Yeah I know but it's a start.

Comment: Does using "new" simply create a sequence of integers stored in memory like malloc, or does it in fact create a list-like object as in Java?

Comment: @ChristianDaley: an actual sequence of integers stored in memory like malloc.

Comment: @Oli, because he wants too. There's nothing wrong with what he's doing. Please just answer questions.

Comment: @owl - Clarifying intent is precisely the purpose of comments.  As I pointed out four years ago, there are substantially better options in C++.

Comment: @Oliver Charlesworth and all of them use malloc under the hood anyway

Answer (score 115, accepted):

`Static` is a keyword with many meanings, and in this particular case, it means **not global** (paraphrasing)

It means that each **`.cpp` file has its own copy** of the variable. Thus, when you initialize in `main.cpp`, **it is initialized ONLY in `main.cpp`**. The other files have it still uninitialized.

First thing to fix this would be to remove the keyword `static`. That would cause the "Multiple definitions issue". To fix this you should define the variable in a `.cpp` file and just extern declare it in a header file.

---

Edit: You are just allocating memory to it, **doesnt count as initialization**. You need to initialize the memory to 0 after allocation.

You can use `new int[128]()` instead of your more verbose `malloc` syntax, and this would [perform initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7546745/1520364) as well? Or you could take the easy road (thats what its there for) and use [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/)

Answer (score 32):

The key is this:

```
static int *pieces;
```

You said you put that in your header.  This is not the way to export a symbol.  Any file that includes the header will get its own static version of an uninitialised pointer called `pieces`.

Instead, you put this in your header:

```
extern int *pieces;

extern int init_pieces();
```

And in the source file, you do this:

```
static const size_t num_pieces = 128;

int *pieces = 0;

int init_pieces()
{
    pieces = malloc( num_pieces * sizeof(int) );
    return pieces != NULL;
}
```

Now when you include your header, your source file will know to get `pieces` from somewhere else, and will wait for the linker to work out where.  I also suggested an 'init' function for the array.  I did not put a 'release' function in, however.

Note this is all C, not C++.  If you're using C++ you should really use `new` or better still, use a `vector`.

Also, when using statics in C++, be mindful of this: [C++ static initialization order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005685/c-static-initialization-order)

Answer (score 10):

In C++17 standard, you can use `inline` specifier instead of static. For variables this means every object unit will have a copy of the variable, but linker will choose only one of them.
Or, as stated on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline):

> An inline function or inline variable (since C++17) has the following
>   properties:
>
> 1) There may be more than one definition of an inline
>   function or variable (since C++17) in the program as long as each
>   definition appears in a different translation unit and (for non-static
>   inline functions and variables (since C++17)) all definitions are
>   identical. For example, an inline function or an inline variable
>   (since C++17) may be defined in a header file that is #include'd in
>   multiple source files.
>
> 2) The definition of an inline function or
>   variable (since C++17) must be present in the translation unit where
>   it is accessed (not necessarily before the point of access).
>
> 3) An inline function or variable (since C++17) with external linkage (e.g.
>   not declared static) has the following additional properties:
>
> ```
> 1) It must be declared inline in every translation unit.
>
> 2) It has the same address in every translation unit.
> ```

Supported in ([source](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support#C.2B.2B17_features)):

- MSVC since version 19.12 (VS 2017 15.5)
- GCC 7
- Clang 3.9
- ICC 18.0

In this case, it means you can replace

```
static int *pieces;
```

with

```
inline int *pieces;
```

Comment: inline fixed soo much errors.. I couldn't do anything without this command, if I included a `header guard` it would give errors, if I used `static` it would give other errors I couldn't figure out how to add global variables in a separate header, which I wanted to add to main  cpp file.

Answer (score 3):

For high performance code on various architectures, you may want a malloc-y allocation rather than generic new.  That is because you would wrap it with something like mymalloc() and then use architecture dependent functions, such as ones that implement the proper alignment to avoid cache misses and do other nifty things provided by the hardware manufacturer, such as IBM (Bluegene) or Intel (MIC).  All of these optimized allocation routines have the malloc type framework.