# thread_local variable not consistent within a thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-local

I have a variable in file tracker.hpp:

```
namespace TRIALS
{
    static thread_local int a = -1;
}
```

I have another class in file called EMP in ema.hpp/ema.cpp

```
namespace Algo
{
    class EMP
    {
        public:
            void Sample();
    };
}
```

```
namespace Algo
{
    void EMP::Sample()
    {
        std::cout << "model " << std::this_thread::get_id() << " " << &TRIALS::a << " " << TRIALS::a << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Then my main file I have

```
auto model = Algo::EMP();

void Simulate(const int a)
{
    TRIALS::a = a;
    model.Sample()
    std::cout << "worker " << std::this_thread::get_id() << " " << &TRIALS::a << " " << TRIALS::a << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << &TRIALS::a << std::endl;
    const int nthreads = 1;

    std::cout << "main " << std::this_thread::get_id() << " " << &TRIALS::a << " " << TRIALS::a << std::endl;

    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    for(int i=0; i<nthreads; ++i)
    {
        threads.emplace_back(&Simulate, i);
    }

    for(auto &thread : threads)
    {
        thread.join();
    }

    std::cout << "main " << std::this_thread::get_id() << " " << &TRIALS::a << " " << TRIALS::a << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I am just running one thread for debugging but this is the output:

0x7f9540b621d8

main 140279012532800 0x7f9540b621d8 -1             (As expected)

model 140278985606912 0x7f953f1b469c -1             (Shouldn't this be 0??)

worker 140278985606912 0x7f953f1b4698 0             (As expected)

main 140279012532800 0x7f9540b621d8 -1             (As expected)

I was under the impression that each thread has it's own local copy of TRIALS::a. The a in model correctly gets incremented but when it returns from the function in the same thread, the value is still 0. I am printing out the thread ids and the address of a for good measure and I am seeing that there are actually 3 different versions of TRIALS::a despite only two total threads.

As a bonus question, what is the difference between `static thread_local int a` and `thread_local int a` ?

Comment: Do you know what `static` variable is?

Comment: What kind of compiler/standard library/target operating system do you use. Thread local is really run-time specific thing.

Comment: i'm using gcc 7.4, with ubuntu 18.04

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I know in the context of normal static, I would think that thread_local static would have just one copy of the variable in question for each thread

Comment: @john So, what does the "normal static" mean?

Comment: Each `.cpp` file gets its own copy. You need `extern` instead of `static` to share a global between files.

Comment: @freakish so in ema.hpp and main.cpp I need extern thread_local int TRIALS::a; ?

Comment: @john You need `extern` in `.hpp` file and then you need to define (and possibly initialize) the variable in one of the `.cpp` files.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I was under the impression that static indicates that the variable is only init once. So every time I reference TRIALS::a it is the same memory location

Comment: @john on the contrary. `static` here means "not global". See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14349877/static-global-variables-in-c/14349916 `static` is weird and context dependent. One of the worst C++ constructs.

Comment: @john "_I was under the impression that static indicates that the variable is only init once._" I am wondering now.. What gave you such impression? What gave you an impression, that non-static variables might be initialized twice?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your example `static` makes that `thread_local` object use internal linkage, so that each translation unit (.cpp file) has its own copy of the variable.

See [storage class specifiers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration) for details:

> The `thread_local` keyword is only allowed for objects declared at namespace scope, objects declared at block scope, and static data members. It indicates that the object has thread storage duration. **It can be combined with `static` or `extern` to specify internal or external linkage (except for static data members which always have external linkage), respectively, but that additional static doesn't affect the storage duration.**

I.e. you may like to drop that `static` keyword, so that you only have one copy of the object in the entire application. In the header file do:

```
namespace TRIALS {
    extern thread_local int a;
}
```

And in one of the `.cpp`:

```
thread_local int TRIALS::a = -1;
```

In C++17, you can make the variable `inline` to avoid having to provide its definition in a `.cpp`:

```
namespace TRIALS {
    inline thread_local int a = -1;
}
```

Comment: If I drop the static, compiling complains that there are multiple definitions of TRIALS::a which makes sense since I am including the file in ema.hpp and main.cpp

Comment: @john that's when `extern` comes to play.

Comment: @john Added an example for you.

Comment: wow awesome! thanks @MaximEgorushkin. Looks like I have to relearn static and extern

Comment: Thanks @freakish I will have to relearn static and extern. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction

Comment: @john don't worry, it took me years to fully understand this s**t. Good luck!