# C++ new * char aren't empty

Tags: c++, pointers, null, char

I had one question.

I developing server in ASIO and packets are in pointed char.

When i create new char (ex. `char * buffer = new char[128];`) i must clean it manually to nulls.

By:

```
for(int i =0;i<128;i++)
{
buffer[i] = 0x00;
}
```

I doing something wrong, that char isn't clear ?

Comment: Your question is already answered by [Do the parentheses after the type name make a difference with new?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/620137/do-the-parentheses-after-the-type-name-make-a-difference-with-new).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You do not have to loop over an array of un-initialized values. You can dynamically instantiate array of zeros like this:

```
char * buffer = new char[128](); // all elements set to 0
                             ^^
```

Answer (score 14):

There are two types of ways of calling the new operator in C++ - default initialised and zero initialised.

To default initialise (which will leave the value undefined) call:

```
int * i = new int;
```

It is then undefined behavoir to read or use this value until its been set.

To zeroinitialise (which will set to 0) use:

```
int * i = new int();
```

This also works with arrays:

```
int * i = new int[4]; // ints are not initialised, you must write to them before reading them
int * i = new int[4](); // ints all zero initialised
```

There's some more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546620/operator-new-initializes-memory-to-zero)

Answer (score 3):

Allocated memory will not be clear, it will contain random stuff instead. That's how memory allocation works. You have to either run a `for`-loop or use `memset` to clear it manually.

Answer (score 2):

You also can use [calloc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3f8w183e%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). It initializes each elem to 0 automaticaly.
e.g:

```
 char* buffer = (char *) calloc (128, sizeof (char))
```

First param is number of blocks to be allocated. Second is size of block.
This function returns void* so you have to convert its value to (char *)
If you use calloc (or malloc or any "pure c" allocation functions) you'd better use [free](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/we1whae7%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) function to deallocate memory instead of delete.