# Why this app doesn't consume as much memory as expected

Tags: c++, linux, performance, memory, process

I wrote a simple application to test memory consumption. In this test application, I created four processes to continually consume memory, those processes won't release the memory unless the process exits.

I expected this test application to consume the most memory of RAM and cause the other application to slow down or crash. But the result is not the same as expected. Below is the code:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <unistd.h>
 #include <list>
 #include <vector>

 using namespace std;
 unsigned short calcrc(unsigned char *ptr, int count)
 {
     unsigned short crc;
     unsigned char i;

     //high cpu-consumption code 
     //implements the CRC algorithm
     //CRC is Cyclic Redundancy Code
 }


 void* ForkChild(void* param){
    vector<unsigned char*>  MemoryVector;
    pid_t PID = fork();
    if (PID > 0){
        const int TEN_MEGA = 10 * 10 * 1024 * 1024;
        unsigned char* buffer = NULL;
        while(1){
            buffer  = NULL;
            buffer = new unsigned char [TEN_MEGA];
            if (buffer){
                 try{
                    calcrc(buffer, TEN_MEGA);
                    MemoryVector.push_back(buffer);
                 } catch(...){
                    printf("An error was throwed, but caught by our app!\n");
                    delete [] buffer;
                    buffer = NULL;
                 }
            }
            else{
                 printf("no memory to allocate!\n");
                 try{
                     if (MemoryVector.size()){
                        buffer = MemoryVector[0];
                        calcrc(buffer, TEN_MEGA);
                        buffer = NULL;
                     } else {
                        printf("no memory ever allocated for this Process!\n");
                        continue;
                     }
                 } catch(...){
                    printf("An error was throwed -- branch 2," 
                           "but caught by our app!\n");
                    buffer = NULL;
                 }
             }
         }  //while(1)
    } else if (PID == 0){
    } else {
      perror("fork error");
    }   

    return NULL;
}


int main(){
int children = 4;
    while(--children >= 0){
    ForkChild(NULL);
    };

    while(1) sleep(1);
    printf("exiting main process\n");
    return 0;
 }
```

1. TOP command

   ```
   PID  USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S  %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND           
   2775 steve     20   0 1503m  508  312 R  99.5  0.0   1:00.46 test              
   2777 steve     20   0 1503m  508  312 R  96.9  0.0   1:00.54 test              
   2774 steve     20   0 1503m  904  708 R  96.6  0.0   0:59.92 test              
   2776 steve     20   0 1503m  508  312 R  96.2  0.0   1:00.57 test
   ```

   Though CPU is high, but memory percent remains 0.0. How can it be possible??
2. Free command

   ```
                     free  shared    buffers     cached          
   Mem:           3083796       0      55996     428296
   ```

   Free memory is more than 3G out of 4G RAM.

Does there anybody know why this test app just doesn't work as expected?

Comment: Linux won't actually allocate memory pages unless you *write* to them. I don't see you writing to your buffer anywhere.

Comment: @한국매미 `new[]` default-initializes all of the items.

Comment: @CoryNelson Yes, and default-initialization of `unsigned char` is a no-op: no write is involved.

Comment: @CoryNelson http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546620/operator-new-initializes-memory-to-zero

Comment: @한국매미 if you set your comments as an answer to this post, I will accept it.

Comment: Also note your TEN_MEGA is really 100MB, not 10...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Linux uses *optimistic memory allocation*: it will not *physically* allocate a page of memory until that page is actually written to. For that reason, you can allocate much more memory than what is available, without increasing memory consumption by the system.

If you want to force the system to allocate (commit) a physical page , then you have to *write* to it.

The following line does not issue any *write*, as it is default-initialization of `unsigned char`, which is a no-op:

```
buffer = new unsigned char [TEN_MEGA];
```

If you want to force a commit, use zero-initialization:

```
buffer = new unsigned char [TEN_MEGA]();
```

Comment: -1 for using `new`?? The question didn't ask for best practices, it asked about memory usage. The answer addresses this concisely -- to introduce anything else would only convolute it.

Answer (score 3):

To make the comments into an answer:

- Linux will not allocate memory pages for a process until it *writes* to them (*copy-on-write*).
- Additionally, you are not writing to your buffer anywhere, as the default constructor for `unsigned char` [does not perform any initializations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546620/operator-new-initializes-memory-to-zero), and `new[]` default-initializes all items.

Comment: very brief and helpful! If your comments come earlier I might have taken a different decision :_)

Answer (score 1):

`fork()` returns the PID in the parent, and 0 in the child. Your `ForkChild` as written will execute all the work in the parent, not the child.

And the standard `new` operator will never return null; it will throw if it fails to allocate memory (but due to overcommit it won't actually do that either in Linux). This means your test of `buffer` after the allocation is meaningless: it will always either take the first branch or never reach the test. If you want a null return, you need to write `new (std::nothrow) ...`. Include `<new>` for that to work.

Comment: yes, you are right, I did make a mistake when judging which one is the child process. Moreover, I also much benefited from your comments on the new operator. Thanks so much for pointing out these!

Answer (score 0):

But your program is infact doing what you expected it to do. As an answer has pointed out (@ Michael Foukarakis's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18917909/2089675)), memory not used is not allocated. In your output of the `top` program, I noticed that the column `virt` had a large amount of memory on it for each process running your program. A little googling later, I saw what this was:

**VIRT** -- `Virtual Memory Size (KiB). The total amount of virtual memory used by the task.` *It includes all code, data and shared libraries plus pages that have been swapped out and pages that have been mapped* **but not used.**

So as you can see, your program does in fact generate memory for itself, but in the form of pages and stored as virtual memory. And I think that is a smart thing to do

A snippet from this [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_(computer_memory))

A **page**, **memory page**, or **virtual page** -- a fixed-length contiguous block of virtual memory, and it is the smallest unit of data for the following:

- memory allocation performed by the operating system for a program; and
- transfer between main memory and any other auxiliary store, such as a hard disk drive.

...Thus a program can address more (virtual) RAM than physically exists in the computer. Virtual memory is a scheme that gives users the illusion of working with a large block of contiguous memory space (perhaps even larger than real memory), when in actuality most of their work is on auxiliary storage (disk). Fixed-size blocks (pages) or variable-size blocks of the job are read into main memory as needed.

**Sources**:

- http://www.computerhope.com/unix/top.htm
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/18917909/2089675
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_(computer_memory)

Comment: oh, I am confused agian. If the program in fact reserved the memory, why I got "free 3083796" from the result of running "shell free" command(RAM of my computer is 4G bytes)?

Comment: If you are still confused, I have updated my answer plus I found [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34422/what-is-the-buffers-column-in-the-output-from-free) on Unix & Linux exchange website which I think the people there will better explain this to you.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to gobble up a lot of memory:

```
int mb = 0;
char* buffer;
while (1) {
    buffer = malloc(1024*1024);
    memset(buffer, 0, 1024*1024);
    mb++;
}
```

I used something like this to make sure the file buffer cache was empty when taking some file I/O timing measurements.

As other answers have already mentioned, your code doesn't ever write to the buffer after allocating it. Here memset is used to write to the buffer.

Comment: Why allocate one MB at a time? Why not allocate a few hundred MB or a GB straight up?

Comment: Sure, just multiply by another 1024.

Comment: Okay, I've edited it a bit. Better? If you still think it is completely valueless, tell me so I can just delete it.

Comment: @Puppy long time ago, but are there any other changes you'd like to see?