# Where ( new int*) points to

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, new-operator

I did some test in vs2012 with codes below:

In Debug Mode:

```
int *b; int *a = b;   //  Crash!!
int *b = *(new int*); int *a = b;  //this is ok
```

I'm curious why it's like this. Does the (new int*)  points to some real memory by default?
And Since it is runs in non-debug mode,, so I wonder if it is ok to write such code

Comment: This is not ok. The `int*` created by `new` is *not* initialised to point to a specific memory location. You are seeing *Undefined Behaviour*.

Comment: The first one shouldn't crash

Comment: You need to be clearer about how exactly the first line 'crashes'.

Comment: @BoBTFish Surely new int * will return a pointer to a null pointer to an int? i.e. the int * will be initialized to null.

Comment: first can crash while using,cause b is uninitialized variable.Second one is already mentioned on above comment

Comment: @cnicutar: The first one also has undefined behaviour due to using an uninitialised value. There's no reason why it shouldn't crash.

Comment: @atomice: No, `new int*` will give a pointer to an uninitialised pointer.

Comment: @atomice I'm pretty sure, without brackets, the `int*` is entirely uninitialised. With `new int* ()` you would be correct. http://stackoverflow.com/a/7546745/1171191

Comment: I am certain that the comments do not match the code above.  Please fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm curious why it's like this.

Both have undefined behaviour due to using the value of an uninitialised object. While it's surprising that this should crash, there's no reason to assume it won't go wrong in some unpredictable way.

Dereferencing the uninitialised pointer (e.g. `int a = *b;` rather than `int *a = b;`), would be more likely to cause a crash. Are you sure you weren't doing that?

> Does the (new int*) points to some real memory by default?

The `int**` returned by `new int*` does. The `int*` that it points to is uninitialised.

> if it is ok to write such code

It's never OK to write code with undefined behaviour. Even if it appears to "work", it will come back to bite you when you least expect it.

Comment: Regarding the first example, I could not find any relevant reference which would make it UB. The closest I came across is 4.1.1 `If the object to which the glvalue refers is not
an object of type T and is not an object of a type derived from T, or if the object is uninitialized, a program
that necessitates this conversion has undeﬁned behavior.` (conv.lval) - from n3242 (C++11 draft). Are you suggesting `int *a = b` is an `lvalue to rvalue conversion?`

Comment: @Abhijit: Yes, that's right. `b` is an _lvalue_, and must be converted to an _rvalue_ to use its value.