# Avoiding initialization by default constructor in C++

Tags: c++, gcc, clang

I need to be sure that a constructor does not initialize some member variables:

```
struct A{
    int a, b;
};
struct B: A{
    int c;
    B():c(42){}
}

char data[sizeof(B)];
B *v=reinterpret_cast<B*>(data);
v->a=42;
v->b=42;
new (v) B;
```

I want A to be defined in such a way that the placement new operator does not modify `v->a` and `v->b`. How should I do that?

A nasty hack would be to store the needed values of `v->a` and `v->b` in thread-local variables and then copying them in `A::A()`. However this won't work if the constructor of `B` creates another `A` so I'll need a stack of them. Is there a faster way?

Comment: As of C++20, you can use `reinterpret_cast` to create suitably trivial objects with no constructor called at all; this piecemeal approach just isn't C++.

Answer (score 1):

You probably cannot guarantee that the "old" `A` is untouched without resorting to non-standard methods (aka "nasty hacks"), since in general a compiler is allowed to prepare your new, uninitialized `A` as it sees fit.

Here's my suggestion, which is however quite insecure, relying on undefined behaviour and with decent chances to work only if both `A` and `B` have standard layout (no `virtual` functions, etc.):

```
char data[sizeof(B)];
// initialize your A object at *data

class B_minus_A {
   int c;
}

new (v+sizeof(A)) B_minus_A;   // (beware the alignment issues!)

B *v=reinterpret_cast<B*>(data);
```

In alternative, an orthodix way is creating a constructor for `B` accepting an `A` argument, and passing it the `A` object that it will overwrite. This is guaranteed to work, the obvious disadvantage is that you pay the cost of two copies (from `*data` to the argument stack of B's constructor and vice versa), and you must be allowed to modify the source code of `B`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're working directly with hardware, or on some really high performance code to need to be doing this.

Placement new will call the constructors for `A` and `B` in that order. Since neither modifies `a` or `b`, you're safe. If your constructor modified either variable, you'd need to change the constructor.

Comment: What about debugging tools like msan/asan? They might overwrite the values in the default constructor.

Comment: I haven't used msan/asan directly myself, but I doubt they will attempt to overwrite any memory during placement new. You'll have to test. Initialize your array to some value, and then call placement new.

Comment: Sadly gcc zero-initializes before placement new.

Comment: According to one answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546620/operator-new-initializes-memory-to-zero:

In C++11, the language used is that the allocated objects are default-initialized which for non-class types means that no initialization is performed. This is different from the meaning of default-initialized in C++03.

Try enabling -std=c++11

Comment: I care about what gcc and clang do. And they might zero-initialize.

Comment: If you test it with `-std=c++11` and they follow the standard and don't do it now, I wouldn't expect them to revert to not following the standard later.

Comment: Sadly, when I tested gcc did zero-initialize.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. That appears to be in direct conflict with the standard.

Comment: @AdamLeggett No, it isn't. The compiler is free to clobber the memory as it sees fit, because no well-defined code can observe the value.