# Initializing array in cpp and padding with zeros

Tags: c++, arrays, padding, variable-length-array

I'm new a c++, switched from matlab to run simulations faster.
I want to initialize an array and have it padded with zeros.

```
    # include <iostream>
# include <string>
# include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int nSteps = 10000;
    int nReal = 10;
    double H[nSteps*nReal];
    return 0;
}
```

It produces an error:

```
expected constant expression    
cannot allocate an array of constant size 0    
'H' : unknown size
```

How do you do this simple thing? Is there a library with a command such as in matlab:

```
zeros(n);
```

Comment: `std::vector<double> H(nSteps*nReal);`

Comment: C-style arrays are mainly there for historical reasons, try to avoid them. They have weird behaviour such as not being able to have the size set at runtime, and causing stack overflows.

Comment: Adding `const`/`constexpr` to both sizes should fix your problem.

Comment: Can't reproduce the error. What compiler are you using?

Comment: visual studio express 2010

Comment: @sergej: Probably one that doesn't allow variable length arrays (which are not standard) by default.

Comment: adding {const} indeed sovled the problem, but  I also define arrays with lengths defined in the runtime. the {std::vector<double>...} did not do anything

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stack-based arrays with a single intializer are zero-filled until their end, but you need to make the array bounds equal to be `const`.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{       
    const int nSteps = 10;
    const int nReal = 1;
    const int N = nSteps * nReal;
    double H[N] = { 0.0 };
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        std::cout << H[i];
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ded579c603c599d2)

For dynamically allocated arrays, you best use `std::vector`, which also does not require compile-time known bounds

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    int nSteps = 10;
    int nReal = 1;
    int N = nSteps * nReal;
    std::vector<double> H(N);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        std::cout << H[i];
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1a33eabd8bdd9451).

Alternatively (but not recommended), you can [manually allocate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7546620/819272) a zero-filled array like

```
double* H = new double[nSteps*nReal](); // without the () there is no zero-initialization
```

Comment: thanks using the vector library helped me with both issus, very helpful for my kind of programming!

Comment: Note that you don't need to use an enum pre-C++11. You can just use `const`. (and since I don't think VS2010 has `constexpr`, `const` is probably what he would use)

Comment: @BenjaminLindley thanks, updated. I am so used to using `constexpr` nowadays that I didn't realise this. It's only for non-type template parameters that you can't always use `const` variables (depending on linkage etc.), and could need `constexpr`.

Answer (score 2):

If you know length in advance you can just do

```
#define nSteps 10000
#define nReal 10
```

Then

```
double H[nSteps*nReal] = {0};
```

Or alternatively you can as well add `const` keyword to your sizes instead of using `define`s.

Comment: Better to use `constexpr` over MACRO.