# Is it safe to access a `std::vector`'s reserved but not sized-in memory, as raw memory?

Tags: c++, memory-management, c++14, stdvector

If one wants to allocate a block of memory without initializing it to zeros, is it safe to do the following?

```
std::vector<uint8_t> block(0);
block.reserve(10000000);
// now access block.data()[0] through block.data()[9999999] as raw uninitialized memory
```

If not, is there a more recent tool for this job, than `malloc` and `free`?

Comment: @Slava `std::array` is on stack and wouldn't `new char[]` initialize the memory?

Comment: `new` is not required to initialize embeded types, but in dev environment `malloc` may do it, so you would not win anything by using it vs `new`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have compile time constant and relatively small size you can use `std::array`:

```
std::array<uint8_t,10000> block;
```

if not use raw memory:

```
std::unique_ptr<uint8_t[]> block( new uint8_t[size] );
```

or after c++14

```
auto block = std::make_unique<uint8_t[]>( size );
```

Comment: Consider using std::make_unique instead in your code.

Comment: @AdvSphere unfortunately you cannot use `make_unique` with array

Comment: .@Slava the following code is valid: `std::unique_ptr<X[]> block {std::make_unique<X[]>(size)};`.

Comment: Hmm I always thought that `std::make_unque` does not work with arrays, you always learn something new, updated

Answer (score 3):

It might be "safe" but you are breaking the class design. And in some standard C++ support libraries, the vector and its iterators will call `abort()` in debug mode because you violated invariant asserts.

So don't do it.

If you just want big uninitialized blocks you can still use `new char[size]` and `unique_ptr`

Comment: Wouldn't `new char[]` initialize the memory?

Comment: @Museful Not as far as I know. Primitive types and POD types don't automatically initialize.

Comment: @Museful No, it does not initialize the memory (or at least, there's no guarantee) https://stackoverflow.com/a/7546745/1896169

Comment: Just a note: allocating a lot of memory often confuses newbies because it *does* look like it got set to zero. But this is not a C or C++ guarantee; it happens because the C support library (msvcrt or glibc) requests a new block of memory from the operating system. Which is set to all zeroes for security reasons.