# The behavior of C++ new with an empty parenthesized list of arguments

Tags: c++

I am trying to understand the rules that regulate memory initialization in `new int` and `new int()`. Some people suggest that the former leaves memory uninitialized, whereas the latter will initialize it to zero (e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546620/operator-new-initializes-memory-to-zero) question). However, I cannot find these rules in the documentation. [C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) says the following:

> For non-array type, the single object is constructed in the acquired
> memory area.
>
> - If initializer is absent, the object is default-initialized.
> - If initializer is a parenthesized list of arguments, the object is direct-initialized.
> - If initializer is a brace-enclosed list of arguments, the object is list-initialized.

First, it's not quite clear from these statements whether `new int()` corresponds to the absent initializer or the initializer with a parenthesized list of arguments. Is an empty pair of parentheses still a parenthesized list?

Second, neither default-initialization nor direct-initialization seem to initialize the value to zero in this case. Default initialization leaves the value uninitialized unless it's a class type. Direct initialization does not seem to be applicable as it requires a **nonempty** parenthesized list of expressions or braced-init-lists.

Interestingly enough, for **array types** C++ reference clearly and explicitly states that

> If initializer is an empty pair of parentheses, each element is
> value-initialized.

But where are the rules for non-array types with an empty parenthesized list?

Comment: `new int()` is counts as "parenthesized list of arguments". It does the same initialization to the memory that `auto i = int();` does... A brace enclosed list would be `new int{}`, which has the same effect for type `int`...

Comment: @paddy I see, value initialization indeed specifies that. Still, somewhat strange that the documentation for new doesn't even mention value initialization among possible options for non-array types.

Comment: It says right there in the "Construction" section: _"If initializer is an empty pair of parentheses, each element is value-initialized."_

Comment: @paddy That's about array types. I was talking about non-array types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But where are the rules for non-array types with an empty parenthesized list?

The rule for `new T()` can be seen at [value initialization documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization):

> ```
> new T ()  (2)
> ```
>
> **Value initialization is performed** in these situations:
>
> 2,6) when an object with dynamic storage duration is created by a new-expression with the initializer **consisting of an empty pair of parentheses or braces** (since C++11);

(emphasis mine)

This means that `new int()` uses *value initialization*.