# Is it a good idea to initialize an array in C++ using MKL functions?

Tags: c++, initialization, intel-mkl

I wonder if it is a good idea to initialize an array to zero in C++ as follows:

```
const int n = 100;
double* x = new double[n];
cblas_dscal(n,0.0,x,1);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

There is no need for an extra call to a mkl function. Just do:

```
const int n = 100;
double* x = new double[n]();
```

This is a C++ feature, explained in more detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2204380/1038318).

Answer (score 1):

Better is to use a vector, which lets you specify the initial value as an optional parameter (default 0)

`std::vector<double> x(n, 0.0);`