# Is it ok if we remove [-Wreturn-local-addr] (warning: address of local variable returned) by using static keyword in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I've a function :

```
int* sumCalc(int *p1, int *p2, int n1, int n2)
{
    int sum[100] = {0};// = new int[n1+n2];
    for(int i = 0; i < n1+n2; ++i)
    {
        sum[i] = p1[i] + p2[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

I'm calling this function from main() by writing :

```
int *sum = sumCalc(p1, p2, n1, n2);
```

So here I'm gonna get Warning.

To remove warning I changed my int array `sum[100]` as static and then I'm returning sum.

```
int* sumCalc(int *p1, int *p2, int n1, int n2)
{
    static int sum[100] = {0};// = new int[n1+n2];
    for(int i = 0; i < n1+n2; ++i)
    {
        sum[i] = p1[i] + p2[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

So is it a good practice to make the local variable static?

And if I to take the memory for array `sum[100]` from the heap then also I think this error would not be there. But can you tell how use new operator here and initialize all elements of array to zero?

Comment: That depends whether you want calls to `sumCalc` affecting the previous return values. FWIW, this function is already implemented as `std::transform`.

Comment: @chris: Not quite, transform takes one input range, this one has two.

Comment: Do you really need to initialize all the elements to zero? You overwrite them immediately after.

Comment: In general, you never want to think of any programming practice as "removing a warning".   Understand what the code in question actually does, why it is a problem, what your proposed fix will do, and then think about whether that is what you want.

Comment: I think a best solution is to return a `std::vector<int>` so you don't need to care about the memory.

Comment: @Galik Worrying about that is a micro-optimization that's unimportant 99.99% of all times (and in this case it makes absolutely no difference anyhow). Zero initialising all memory by default is a rather useful practice. There are much bigger problems with the code really.

Comment: The biggest problems are a) If `n1+n2 > 100` you write to non allocated memory. b) I assume n1 and n2 refer to the size of the two arrays passed in by pointer. Adding those two together makes no sense - actually if n1 != n2 it's not clear what the code should do anyhow.

Comment: @Voo It's not an optimization it's simply not adding needless code for no reason. Zero-initializing memory by default serves no real purpose except maybe to hide the occasional bug for longer.

Comment: @Galik Do I really now have to go and find one of the million security bugs that would've been avoided by people zero initializing their locals? Yes, yes the elusive person who never writes a bug doesn't need it, but in real life people make mistakes and this one of those little things that at least diminishes the problems when they happen.

Comment: @MooingDuck, It has an overload taking two. Comes in really handy when you need it and don't have `zip`.

Comment: can someone please replace the line `static int sum[100] = {0};` with the `new` keyword.. because when I write `int sum[] = new int[100];` or `int sum[] = new int[100]();` then it gives me error,

Comment: @Ayushibhardwaj `int* sum = new int[n1+n2];` Don't forget to *delete* it with `delete[] sum;` when you are done with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trouble is that in the first version, the variable is allocated off of the stack and not the heap.  That means when the function returns, the `sum` variable disappears, and what you get is a random leftover address that points nowhere.

Yes, declaring the variable as static will make the warning disappear, but it is poor practice.  What that tells the compiler is that there is only ever one copy of the `sum` variable, no matter how many times that the function is called.  That means if you call the function again, the array will have the same contents.

```
int array1[3] = {1, 2, 3};
int array2[3] = {2, 3, 4};

int array3[2] = {5, 6};
int array4[2] = {7, 8};

int* returned = sumCalc(array1, array2, 3, 3); 
int* gotcha = sumCalc(array3, array4, 2, 2); //Now returned is the same array as gotcha!
```

This can cause confusion because if you were expecting `returned` and `gotcha` to be different, you're in for a surprise.  They will both be pointed to `{12, 14}`.

To allocate off of the heap, you have to use the `new` operator.  You can find a number of ways to initialize the array in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204176/how-to-initialise-memory-with-new-operator-in-c).

Edit: P.S. - Don't forget to `delete` the pointer allocated with `new` at the end of the program.

Comment: The sample code you posted has much bigger troubles than reusing the same array - it will foremost cause quite a lot of out of bound reads (this is really a problem of the design of the function, but is clearly a much bigger issue than the reuse)

Comment: can you please replace the line `static int sum[100] = {0};` with the new keyword.. because when I write `int sum[] = new int[100];` or `int sum[] = new int[100]();` then it gives me error,

Comment: Ayushi, the line I believe is `int* sum = new int[100]()`.  It's not a fixed-length array when you use `new`.

Answer (score 0):

The keyword `static` when used in block scope would make

- the `sum` behave like a function variable
- it will be shared between different invocations of the functions
- The above may not be desirable.

A work around would be

- Defining `int sum[100] = {0};` inside main
- Passing a pointer to the same by modifying the `sumCalc` signature to something like

  ```
  void sumCalc(int (*ptr)[100),int *p1, int *p2, int n1, int n2)
  // Note the return type is void
  ```

and call it like

```
sumCalc(&sum,p1, p2, n1, n2);
```

And the loop inside the sum would be :

```
for(int i = 0; i < n1+n2; ++i)
{
    (*ptr)[i] = p1[i] + p2[i]; 
}
```

Comment: can you please replace the line `static int sum[100] = {0};` with the new keyword.. because when I write `int sum[] = new int[100];` or `int sum[] = new int[100]();` then it gives me error,

Comment: If you follow this, you don't need the new keyword at all.. Just go with `int sum[100] = {0};` inside the main

Comment: no no I already knew this method to pass the sum array from main() I just wanted to explore more into scope of variables. So I want to use new keyword.