# Will C++ default-initialization set array elements to its default value?

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization, new-operator

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
  int* p = new int[2];
  for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    cout << p[i] << endl;  
  return 0;
}
```

I run it several times. It always produces the following output:

```
0
0
```

Can I assume that C++ default-initialization set array elements to its default value? In this case, can I assume that p's element values are always set to 0?

I have read the following related questions. But they does not specifically address my case:

- [How to initialise memory with new operator in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204176/how-to-initialise-memory-with-new-operator-in-c)
- [Operator new initializes memory to zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546620/operator-new-initializes-memory-to-zero)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Can I assume that C++ default-initialization set array elements to its default value?

No, for [default initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization):

> - if T is an array type, every element of the array is default-initialized;

and the element type is `int`, then

> - otherwise, nothing is done: the objects with automatic storage duration (and their subobjects) are initialized to indeterminate
>     values.

On the other hand, [list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization)(since C++11) like `int* p = new int[2]{};` or `int* p = new int[2]{0};`, or [value initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) like `int* p = new int[2]();` will guarantee that, for `int` all the elements will be zero-initialized.