# Explanation of undefined behaviour, and whether it's truly undefined

Tags: c++, arrays

I have dynamically allocated memory for an array of 5 elements, then tried to print its elements to `std::cout`, which should have left me with a fairly straightforward result. I got something else instead, and it left me with some questions.

My code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int *array = new int[5];

    int array_size = sizeof(array);
    for (int index = 0; index < array_size; index++) {
        std::cout << array[index] << "\n";
    }
    std::cout << "\nThe array is " << array_size << " elements long.";

    return 0;
}
```

This is what this resulted in:

```
0
0
0
0
0
0
132049
0
```

Now, I understand this isn't how things are done, but such a result has left me with several questions.

1. Why is the size of the array 8, and not 5? Originally, I thought that it's becase the memory according to powers of 2, but I have a feeling I'm wrong.
2. What's with 132049?

Comment: `sizeof(array)` is the size of the pointer in bytes.

Comment: Other than that, your array is uninitialized.  Accessing the value of an uninitialized object is undefined behavior.

Comment: Have a read of: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub

Comment: Unrelated to your question: `new`/`new[]` should always be coupled with `delete`/`delete[]`.

Comment: Instead of mananging the dynamic array yourself, you might want to look at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

Comment: @generic_opto_guy std::vector has one situational [dis]advantage of being able to grow. That's not necessarily desirable or even acceptable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code has two problems, each of them leading to undefined behavior.

First, `sizeof(array)` is the size of the pointer in bytes, not the array.  On your machine, a pointer happens to take 8 bytes.  This causes out-of-range access, which is undefined behavior.

Second, `new int[5]` gives you an uninitialized array.  Accessing the value of an uninitialized object is undefined behavior.

To fix these problems, first note that the size of an array returned by `new` is lost.  `sizeof` cannot help you.  You can only provide this information yourself.  Then you have to initialize the elements.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int *array = new int[5]{}; // note: initialization

    int array_size = 5;
    for (int index = 0; index < array_size; index++) {
        std::cout << array[index] << "\n";
    }
    std::cout << "\nThe array is " << array_size << " elements long.";

    return 0;
}
```

This is code is guaranteed to print

```
0
0
0
0
0

The array is 5 elements long.
```

(As long as there is enough memory and output succeeds)

Comment: My assumption, then, would be that allocation and initialization are different procedures? I mean, it seems kinda obvious if you think about it - one is reserving a spot, the other is filling it.

Comment: @IvanT. `new` default-initializes, but default-initialization on a `int` doesn't actually initialize it.  Just like `int x;`.

Comment: @IvanT. You may be interested in the answers to [How to initialise memory with new operator in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204176/how-to-initialise-memory-with-new-operator-in-c).