# Is there a better way to initialize an allocated array in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, initialization

How to write this in another (perhaps shorter) way?
Is there a better way to initialize an allocated array in C++?

```
int main(void) {
   int* a;
   a = new int[10];
   for (int i=0; i < 10; ++i) a[i] = 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this because this question is incredibly vague.  There are an infinite number of programs that fit the stated criteria.  What's your specific problem here?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
 int *a =new int[10](); // Value initialization
```

`ISO C++ Section 8.5/5`

> To value-initialize an object of type T means:
>
> — if T is a class type (clause 9) with a user-declared constructor (12.1), then the default constructor for T is called (and the initialization is ill-formed if T has no accessible default constructor);
>
> — if T is a non-union class type without a user-declared constructor, then every non-static data member and base-class component of T is value-initialized;
>
> — if T is an array type, then each element is value-initialized;
>
> — **otherwise, the object is zero-initialized**

For differences between the terms `zero initialization`, `value initialization` and `default initialization`, read [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1613341/what-do-the-following-phrases-mean-in-c-zero-default-and-value-initializati)

Comment: This *is* better because it deals well with arrays of objects and in a template context. But bear in mind that for the simple example given above the generated code is likely to be very similar (perhaps identical).

Answer (score 22):

How about 3 ways?

```
1.    int *a = new int[10]();

2.    std::vector<int> a(10, 0);

3.    int *a = new int[10];
      memset(a, 0, sizeof(int) * 10);
```

Due to popular demand, a couple more:

```
4.    int *a = new int[10];
      std::fill(a, a + 10, 0);

5.    std::vector<int> a(10);
      std::fill(a.begin(), a.end(), 0);
```

Comment: @Omnifarious: I was actually about to include `fill`, but I just like the number 3 more than 4. :)

Comment: also `int a[10] = {0};` could be an alternative way.

Answer (score 20):

```
std::vector<int> vec(10, 0); 
int *a = &vec.front();
```

Comment: And the 0 isn't even required, since `int()` is the default value.

Answer (score 18):

You could use [`memset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memset)

> Sets the first num bytes of the block of memory pointed by ptr to the specified value (interpreted as an unsigned char).

Comment: Old, I know, but there's really no reason to use `memset`. `std::fill` is a more generic way of getting the same thing (which means the code can be consistent) at no loss.

Comment: Since `memset` changes by _bytes_, it cannot be used for non-zero values. http://stackoverflow.com/a/17288891/2680660

Answer (score 4):

```
int main(void) { int *a; a = new int[10]; for(int i=0;i<10;++i) a[i]=0; }
```

;-)

Comment: you are right:

`int main(){int i,*a=new int[10];for(i=0;i<10;++i)a[i]=0;}`

Answer (score 3):

```
int *a = (int*) calloc(10, sizeof(*a));
```

(and check if is NULL, or rewrite a safe wrapper against calloc).

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    int *a = new int[10];
    std::fill(a, a + 10, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try something like this:

```
int* initIntArray(int size) {
    int *temp = new int[size];
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        temp[i]=0;
    }
    return temp;
}

int main () {
    int* a = initIntArray(10);
    int* b = initIntArray(10);
    int* c = initIntArray(10);

    //do stuff with arrays

    delete [] a;
    delete [] b;
    delete [] c;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: is there a reason someone voted down this answer?? i'd like to what I did wrong (seriously!! no sarcasm here)

Comment: Your answer seems fine. I don't understand the downvotes either.

Comment: This is just bad advice; it's nearly an exact copy of std::fill_n with downsides but no benefit.

Comment: I didn't down-vote, but I think the problem some may have had is that this doesn't deviate much from the OP's original problem.  I think the OP is trying to eliminate writing a for-loop to do the initialization.

Answer (score 0):

by the way, what about using calloc()?
say

`int i*=(int[10])calloc(10*sizeof(int))`

well i'm just another C guy.. any comment is welcomed here

Comment: Because in C++, people generally use `new` and if you use `calloc` you have to use `free` instead of `delete`.

Comment: Doesn't calloc take two parameters?  Matbe you meant `int i*=(int[10])calloc(10,sizeof(int));`

Answer (score -1):

I'm a C guy and not too sure what "new" really does, but could this work?

```
int
main( void ) {
   int i = 10;              // start at the far end of the array
   int *a = new int[10]; 
   while ( i-- ) a[i] = 0;  // while ( i == 9, 8, 7, ... , 0 )
}
```

Just to show off my new loop-counter favorite: while(condition).

Comment: 1) why is `i` static? 2) Why `while` instead of the established, idiomatic `for`?

Comment: Where is the calloc :P, if you are a C guy ?

Comment: @Konrad: `static` is zero initialized; and `while` is different from `for`.  I agree with you, though: outside the scope of this question, I'd be upset with someone who presented the code shown as a good way of doing things.

Comment: @Andrei, I forgot about calloc, dang it :-) 

I started trying this technique about 6 mmonths ago; it's beginning to seem cleaner and more obvious. Tons of off-by-one mistakes in the beginning. A somewhat more obscure version:<pre><code>
    int i = 10;
    int *a = new int[10];
    while ( i-- ) a[i] = 0;</code></pre>