# Using memset for integer array in C

Tags: c, memset

```
char str[] = "beautiful earth";
memset(str, '*', 6);
printf("%s", str);

Output:
******ful earth
```

Like the above use of memset, can we initialize only a few integer array index values to 1 as given below?

```
int arr[15];
memset(arr, 1, 6);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [memset integer array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7202411/memset-integer-array)

Comment: Nope. `memset()` casts down to a byte and dupes it across the region.

Comment: You could always read the memset documentation to find out what it does.

Comment: @JoeFrambach The accepted answer to that question doesn't apply here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does "memset(arr, -1, sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int))" not clear an integer array to -1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7202411/why-does-memsetarr-1-sizeofarr-sizeofint-not-clear-an-integer-array-t)

Answer (score 89, accepted):

No, you cannot use `memset()` like this. The [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memset) says (emphasis mine):

> The `memset()` function fills the first `n` **bytes** of the memory area pointed to by `s` with the constant byte `c`.

Since an `int` is usually 4 bytes, this won't cut it.

---

If you (*incorrectly!!*) try to do this:

```
int arr[15];
memset(arr, 1, 6*sizeof(int));    //wrong!
```

then the first 6 `int`s in the array will actually be set to 0x01010101 = 16843009.

The only time it's ever really acceptable to write over a "blob" of data with non-byte datatype(s), is `memset(thing, 0, sizeof(thing));` to "zero-out" the whole struture/array. This works because NULL, 0x00000000, 0.0, are all completely zeros.

---

The solution is to use a `for` loop and set it yourself:

```
int arr[15];
int i;

for (i=0; i<6; ++i)    // Set the first 6 elements in the array
    arr[i] = 1;        // to the value 1.
```

Comment: In my system size of int is 4 bytes. So i tried memset(arr,1,8). But it is initializing the whole array with that 4 byte value instead of filling only first 8 bytes as per my third argument.

Comment: I would be more convinced by your claim memset did this if you start out by initializing the whole array to 0 (using int arr[15] = {0}) and then doing the memset(arr, 1, 8);

And if you still have an array full of 0x01010101's after that, you have a buggy c runtime :-).

Comment: @Jonathon, I agree it's the wrong thing to do, but the claim is that memset is behaving in a way radically different from what it's supposed to do.  I pointed out that probably is not the case and described a way to really check it.

Comment: @MikeWoolf Right. My comment was directed to the OP. Certainly he is free to code whatever he wishes, but if he's hoping to somehow *trick* memset into initializing his array, it's going to end poorly.

Comment: "NULL, 0x00000000, 0.0, are all completely zeros." -- NULL is not necessarily all (or any) 0 bits.

Comment: @JimBalter While you are technically correct, I would be curious to know of any platforms where `NULL` is non-zero.

Comment: off-topic question, I thought memset works on pointers, arr is not a pointer.

Comment: @briankip The array [decays to a pointer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying) here. The `&` is optional in this case; `memset(&arr, ...)` would do the same thing.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Dangerous wording (*'& is optional'*). Both variants work, as memset accepts `void*`, but pointer type is different: `arr` decays to `int*` whereas `&arr` gives a pointer of type `int(*)[15]`!

Comment: @Jacqueline P. If you think this answer is incorrect, the right thing to do is leave a comment, not suggest an edit. That way I can explain why your understanding isn't quite right.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I'm wondering why you don't take the value of `Binary` but take the number of `hexadecimal 16843009 = 0x01010101`?

Comment: An `int` is usually 4 bytes. In that example, *each byte* would be set to the value 1 (0x01). So when you consider the 4-byte integer, its value (regardless of endianness) would be 0x01010101. Perhaps the question should be turned around: why would you consider binary, or octal, or any other base?

Answer (score 27):

Short answer, NO.

Long answer, `memset` sets bytes and works for characters because they are single bytes, but integers are not.

Answer (score 8):

On Linux, OSX and other UNIX like operating systems where `wchar_t` is 32 bits and you can use `wmemset()` instead of `memset()`.

```
#include<wchar.h>
...
int arr[15];
wmemset( arr, 1, 6 );
```

Note that `wchar_t` on MS-Windows is 16 bits so this trick may not work.

Comment: Why would you use this non-portable hack instead of a simple loop?

Answer (score 5):

The third argument of memset is byte size. So you should set total byte size of `arr[15]`

```
memset(arr, 1, sizeof(arr));
```

However probably, you should want to set value 1 to whole elements in arr. Then you've better to set in the loop.

```
for (i = 0; i < sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]); i++) {
    arr[i] = 1;
}
```

Because `memset()` set 1 in each bytes. So it's not your expected.

Comment: But in my system size of int is 4 bytes. So i tried memset(arr,1,8). But it is initializing the whole array with that 4 byte value instead of filling only first 8 bytes as per my third argument

Comment: You must not use constant value 8, you've better to use count of element size. for example `n * sizeof(int)`.

Comment: When calling `memset(arr, 1, 4)`, it become 0x01 0x01 0x01 0x01. But your expected is `0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01`. (This is depend on your CPU archtecture).

Comment: got it. thanks. I tried memset(arr,1,2*sizeof(int)); as you said but still it is initializing the whole array with same value.

Comment: As I wrote in above, you shouldn't use memset if you want to set value 1 each elements (not set 1 each bytes).

Comment: @user1762571 " it is initializing the whole array with that 4 byte value instead of filling only first 8 bytes as per my third argument " -- no, it's only setting 8 bytes. You're misinterpreting the results somehow or you're copying the initial bytes to the rest of the array.

Answer (score 5):

Since nobody mentioned it...

Although you cannot initialize the integers with value `1` using memset, you **can** initialize them with value `-1` and simply change your logic to work with negative values instead.

For example, to initialize the first 6 numbers of your array with `-1`, you would do

```
memset(arr,-1,6*(sizeof int));
```

Furthermore, if you only need to do this initialization once, you can actually declare the array to start with values `1` from compile time.

```
int arr[15] = {1,1,1,1,1,1};
```

Comment: You're technically correct, but if I saw that in a code review, I would probably lose it.

Comment: This will only work on platforms using 2's-complement for representing negative numbers. Even though virtually every platform today is 2's -complement, this is still a hack.

Answer (score 3):

Actually it is possible with `memset_pattern4` which sets 4 bytes at a time.

```
memset_pattern4(your_array, your_number, sizeof(your_array));
```

Comment: it sets 4 **bytes** at a time, not 4 bits

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't [portably] use `memset` for that purpose, unless the desired target value is `0`. `memset` treats the target memory region as an array of bytes, not an array of `int`s.

A fairly popular hack for filling a memory region with a repetitive pattern is actually based on `memcpy`. It critically relies on the expectation that `memcpy` copies data in forward direction

```
int arr[15];

arr[0] = 1;
memcpy(&arr[1], &arr[0], sizeof arr - sizeof *arr);
```

This is, of course, a pretty ugly hack, since the behavior of standard `memcpy` is undefined when the source and destination memory regions overlap. You can write your own version of `memcpy` though, making sure it copies data in forward direction, and use in the above fashion. But it is not really worth it. Just use a simple cycle to set the elements of your array to the desired value.

Comment: memcpy copies multiple bytes in one iteration for optimization so I don't think this trick can actually work on strings larger than 8 chars at least

Answer (score 0):

Memset sets values for data types having 1 byte but integers have 4 bytes or more , so it won't work and you'll get garbage values.
It's mostly used when you are working with char and string types.

Answer (score 0):

The following program shows that we can initialize the array using memset() with -1 and 0 only

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

void printArray(int arr[], int len)
{
        int i=0;
    for(i=0; i<len; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    }
    puts("");
}

int main()
{
    int arrLen = 15;
    int totalNoOfElementsToBeInitialized = 6;

    int arr[arrLen];
    printArray(arr, arrLen);
    memset(arr, -1, totalNoOfElementsToBeInitialized*sizeof(arr[0]));
    printArray(arr, arrLen);
    memset(arr, 0, totalNoOfElementsToBeInitialized*sizeof(arr[0]));
    printArray(arr, arrLen);
    memset(arr, 1, totalNoOfElementsToBeInitialized*sizeof(arr[0]));
    printArray(arr, arrLen);
    memset(arr, 2, totalNoOfElementsToBeInitialized*sizeof(arr[0]));
    printArray(arr, arrLen);
    memset(arr, -2, totalNoOfElementsToBeInitialized*sizeof(arr[0]));
    printArray(arr, arrLen);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you can not use memset to set your arrary to all 1.
Because **memset** works on byte and set every byte to 1.

```
memset(hash, 1, cnt);
```

So once read, the value it will show **16843009 = 0x01010101 = 1000000010000000100000001**
Not **0x00000001**
But if your requiremnt is only for bool or binary value then we can set using C99 standard for C library

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>        //Use C99 standard for C language which supports bool variables

int main()
{
    int i, cnt = 5;
    bool *hash = NULL;
    hash = malloc(cnt);

    memset(hash, 1, cnt);
    printf("Hello, World!\n");

    for(i=0; i<cnt; i++)
        printf("%d ", hash[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

Hello, World!
1 1 1 1 1