# How do this code work without any errors?

Tags: c++

I've this code i wrote that sets the array to 0

```
int arr[4];
memset(arr, 0, sizeof (arr));
```

Very simple, but how the code works without any errors even though `sizeof(arr)` = 16 (4 the array size * 4 for int) and the size i used when i declared the array is 4, How `memset` sets 16 bits to zero and the array i passed as a parameter has the size of 4?

I used `memset(arr, 0, sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr));` to get the real size of the array and the result was accurate and it gives me `4` but how the above code works correctly?

Comment: Read the documentation of the function properly before asking a question on SO.

Comment: why do you use a function from the last century to fiddle around with memory in C++?

Comment: "How memset sets 16 bits to zero" it sets 16 _bytes_ to zero, assuming `sizeof(arr)` == 16.

Comment: Use `C` tag for this question rather than `C++` because this in fact is not `C++` at all. But this question is a legit beginner question, I do not understand the minus votes. Reading the docs always helps but if everybody reads the docs really carefully, there would probably not need to be any stackoverflow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using memset for integer array in c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17288859/using-memset-for-integer-array-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`memset` sets 16 bytes (not bits) to 0. This is correct because the size of your array is 16 bytes, as you correctly stated (4 integers x 4 bytes per integer). `sizeof` knows the number of elements in your array and it knows the size of each element. As you can see in the docs, the third argument of `memset` takes the number of bytes, not the number of elements. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memset/

But be careful with using `sizeof()` where you pass array as `int x[]` or `int* x`. For example the following piece of code will not do what you expect:

```
void foo(int arr[]) {
  auto s = sizeof(arr); // be careful! this won't do what you expect! it will return the size of pointer to array, not the size of the array itself
  ...
}

int a[10];
foo(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

The third parameter is number of bytes. Which is 4*4=16 for your case.

[memset](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memset/)

Answer (score 0):

Actually the first solution is the correct one.

The function [`memset`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memset/) takes as third parameter the *number of bytes* to set to zero.

> *num*:
>   Number of bytes to be set to the value.

[`sizeof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof) returns the number of bytes occupied by the expression.

In your case `sizeof(arr) = 16` which is exactly yhe number of bytes requested by `memset` function.

---

Your second solution:

```
memset(arr, 0, sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr));  // Note that: sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr) == 16 / 4 (generally) == 4 bytes
```

will set only the first 4 bytes to zero, that is the first integer of the array. So that solution is wrong if your intent is to set each element of the array to zero.