# Temporary Object confusion

Tags: c++, temporary

Have a look at this code snippet

```
struct S{ int i; int j;};

int main()
{
   assert(S().i ==  S().j) // is it guaranteed ?
}
```

Why?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> is it guaranteed ?

Yes it is guaranteed. The values of `S().i` and `S().j` would be `0`. `()` implies [value initialization.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1613341/what-do-the-following-phrases-mean-in-c-zero-default-and-value-initializati/1613383#1613383) (that means `i` and `j` would be zero-initialized because `S` is a class without a user defined default constructor)

Comment: In particular, adding `S() {}` (a do-nothing user-defined ctor) to `struct S` will cause `i` and `j` to be left uninitialised, meaning the `assert()` is likely to trigger.

Answer (score 0):

From C++ Standard ISO/IEC 14882:2003(E) point 3.6.2

> Objects with static storage duration (3.7.1) shall be zero-initialized (8.5) before any other initialization
>   takes place.

So this is valid as both variables are zero-initialized.

Comment: I dont see any object with static storage allocation here. Expression `S()` creates a **temporary object** local to the scope of `assert()`.

Comment: You want section 8.5, which discusses the general case of initialization.

Comment: sorry... somehow i thought that he is using global variable

Answer (score -1):

Technically, yes.  They will be initialized to 0 <strike>(at least under a non-debug build for most compilers.  Visual Studio's compiler will usually initialize uninitialized variables to a specific pattern in debug builds)</strike>.

However, if you were sitting in a code review, don't be surprised if you get yelled at for not explicitly initializing your variables.

Comment: Guranteed to be zero. Because of the () braces.