# Difference between default-initialize and value-initialize?

Tags: c++, initialization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do the following phrases mean in C++: zero-, default- and value-initialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1613341/what-do-the-following-phrases-mean-in-c-zero-default-and-value-initializati)

I was reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620137/do-the-parentheses-after-the-type-name-make-a-difference-with-new/620402#620402), so I came across the second word : `value-initialize`. Initially I thought this is same as `default-initialize` but the context hints me that I'm wrong.

So my question is :

What is the difference between *default-initialize* and *value-initialize*?

I would like to understand the difference with some examples.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do the following phrases mean in C++: zero-, default- and value-initialization?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1613341/what-do-the-following-phrases-mean-in-c-zero-default-and-value-initializati)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the standard (8.5/4,5):

> To **default-initialize** an object of
>   type T means:
>   — if T is a non-POD
>   class type the default constructor for
>   T is called (and the initialization is
>   ill-formed if T has no accessible
>   default constructor);
>   — if T is an
>   array type, each element is
>   default-initialized;
>   — otherwise, the
>   object is zero-initialized.

> To **value-initialize** an object of
>   type T means:
>   — if T is a class type
>   (clause 9) with a user-declared
>   constructor (12.1), then the default
>   constructor for T is called (and the
>   initialization is ill-formed if T has
>   no accessible default constructor);
>   —
>   if T is a non-union class type without
>   a user-declared constructor, then
>   every non-static data member and
>   base-class component of T is
>   value-initialized;<sup>96)</sup>
>   — if T is an
>   array type, then each element is
>   value-initialized;
>   — otherwise, the
>   object is zero-initialized

Comment: Warning: This answer is out-of-date for C++11.  See http://stackoverflow.com/q/22233148/368896.  In C++11, for the `default-initialize` case, the `-- otherwise, the object is zero-initialized` is replaced by `-- otherwise, no initialization is performed`.

Answer (score 9):

"default-initialise" gives it the default value as specified by the standard, **which could be garbage**.

"value-initialise" initialises it to a specific value - one set in the constructor, for instance, or optimised by the compiler.

Comment: This helps me remember that when you `value` initialize something, the thing really is getting its VALUES set (even if that means setting them to 0 as a fall-through if no constructor is available), whereas plain old `default` initialization will have no fall-through and values can be uninitialized if no constructor sets their value.  In the spirit of C++, there must be some condition to force the `value` initialization - i.e., you must explicitly pass parentheses, as in `A a();` (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/8860787/368896).

Comment: @Dan Nissenbaum Isn't A a(); a vexing parse issue? Seen as a function declaration?