# Meaning of default initialization changed in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, language-lawyer, c++-faq

C++2003 8.5/5 says:

> To *default-initialize* an object of type T means:
>
> — if T is a non-POD class type (clause 9), the default constructor for T is called (and the initialization is
>   ill-formed if T has no accessible default constructor);
>
> — if T is an array type, each element is default-initialized;
>
> — otherwise, the object is **zero-initialized**.

[Emphasis added.]

The C++2011 standard changed that last item to

> — otherwise, **no initialization is performed**.

This seems like it would be a breaking change for some programs.  Was this intentional?

**Edit**

Here's some code to motivate this question:

```
class Foo {
  public:
    Foo() : m_values() {}

    int m_values[3];
};
```

Before C++11, I thought the explicit mention of `m_values` in the default constructor would *default-initialize* that array.  And since the elements of the array are scalar, I expected that to mean the values were all set to 0.

In C++11, it seems there's no longer a guarantee that this will happen.  But maybe, as Mooing Duck pointed out in the comments, perhaps this is no longer a case of default initialization but some other form which preserves the expected behavior.  Citations welcome.

Comment: the objects are not initialized. so, they are UNINITIALIZED OBJECTS.

Comment: @Victor: He's aware.  His point is that the change from initialized to uninitialized is a breaking change.

Comment: I recall hearing that C++03 didn't have "value-initialization" vs "default initialization" vs "zero initialization" or something.  Is it possible that things that were previously default initialized are now zero initialized, which makes this into a not-breaking change?

Comment: `m_values` should be value-initialized because it is part of the member initializer list with empty parentheses.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The final effects are almost the same.  In C++03, the use of *default-initialize* was restricted to non-POD class type, so the last point never applied.  In C++11, the standard simplifies the wording by eliminating the condition with regards to where default-initialization was used, and changes the definition of default-initialization to cover all of the cases in a way to correspond what happened before.

Comment: Specifically, C++03 8.5/9: If no initializer is specified for an object, and the object is of (possibly cv-qualified) non-POD class type (or array thereof), the object shall be default-initialized; if the object is of const-qualified type, the underlying class type shall have a user-declared default constructor. Otherwise, if no initializer is specified for a nonstatic object, the object and its subobjects, if any, have an indeterminate initial value; if the object or any of its subobjects are of const-qualified type, the program is ill-formed.

Comment: vs. C++11 8.5/11: If no initializer is specified for an object, the object is default-initialized; if no initialization is performed, an
object with automatic or dynamic storage duration has indeterminate value.

Comment: I don't quite I understand this answer.  Are you saying that since the `m_values` array in the example is POD that default-initialize never applied, not even in C++03?  Can you clarify?  If I construct a `Foo` as shown above, will the values in `m_values` be 0 or indeterminate?

Comment: @JamesKanze:  Your answer looks helpful to many, but I still have the questions from me previous comment.  If you could clear those up, I'd happily accept it.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy: Because of the explicit `m_values()` in the contructor, the array is never default initialized in any version of C++; it is value initialized (which is the same in C++03 and 11).  If that was not present, the array be be uninitialized in C++03 and default initialized in C++11.

Answer (score 3):

According to [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization) (because it uses friendlier language than the standard):

> Default initialization is performed in three situations:
>
> > 3) when a base class or a non-static data member is not mentioned in a
> >     constructor initializer list and that constructor is called.
>
> Value initialization is performed in three situations:
>
> > 3,7) when a non-static data member or a base class is initialized
> >     using a member initializer with an empty pair of parentheses `or braces (since C++11)`

Note that the C++11 part belongs with the `or braces`, not with the entire paragraph.

And:

> To value-initialize an object of type T means:
>   — if T is an array type, then each element is value-initialized;
>   — otherwise, the object is zero-initialized

So in C++11 *default-initialization* does not zero-initialize members but *value-initialization* does.

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking, the definition of *default-initialize* has changed from C++03 to C++11. But one has also to take into account that the situations when an object is _default-initialize_d changed:

§8.5p9 C++03 states:

> If no initializer is specified for an object, and the object is of (possibly cv-qualified) non-POD class type (or array thereof), the object shall be default-initialized; if the object is of const-qualified type, the underlying class type shall have a user-declared default constructor. Otherwise, if no initializer is specified for a nonstatic object, the object and its subobjects, if any, have an indeterminate initial value; if the object or any of its subobjects are of const-qualified type, the program is ill-formed.

§8.5p11 C++11 states:

> If no initializer is specified for an object, the object is default-initialized; if no initialization is performed, an object with automatic or dynamic storage duration has indeterminate value.

As @JamesKanze already pointed out, *default-initialization* is performed in C++03 when no initializer for an object of non-POD class type is specified. In C++11 an object (of arbitrary type) is *default-initialized* if no initializer is specified. Because of this change, the definition of *default-initialize* had also to be changed in order to be compatible with C++03.

---

Your example has nothing to do with *default-initialization*. It has been always the case that an object whose initializer is an empty set of parentheses is *value-initialized*.