# What Does cv-qualified Mean?

Tags: c++, declaration, definition, qualifiers

I have started seeing the term "cv-qualified" being thrown around a lot.

[An answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27506091/2642059) to my last question:

> if T is a (possibly **cv-qualified**) class type (Clause 9), the default constructor (12.1) for T is called

Can someone define that for me?

Comment: I would assume it's the opposite of that, at least.

Comment: It's the [`const` and `volatile` type qualifiers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

c in cv means const and v means volatile.

From the C++ Standard (3.9.3 CV-qualifiers)

- The term object type (1.8) includes the cv-qualifiers specified in the decl-specifier-seq (7.1), declarator (Clause 8), type-id (8.1), or newtype - id (5.3.4) when the object is created.
- A const object is an object of type const T or a non-mutable subobject of such an object.
- A volatile object is an object of type volatile T, a subobject of such an object, or a mutable subobject of a const volatile object.
- A const volatile object is an object of type const volatile T, a non-mutable subobject of such an object, a const subobject of a volatile object, or a non-mutable volatile subobject of a const object.

Answer (score 23):

c-v qualified means const and volatile...For e.g:-

```
// non cv_qualified 
int first; 
char *second; 

// cv-qualified 
const int third; 
volatile char * fourth;
```