# How to make sure your object is zero-initialized?

Tags: c++11, initialization, zero, default-constructor, value-initialization

**Update**: I'm looking to see if there's a way to zero-initialize the entire class at once, because technically, one can forget adding a '`= 0`' or '`{}`' after each member. One of the comments mentions that an explicitly defaulted no-arg c-tor will *enable* zero-initialization during value-initialization of the form `MyClass c{};`. Looking at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization I'm having trouble figuring out which of the statements specify this.

Initialization is a complex topic now since C++11 has changed meaning and syntax of various initialization constructs. I was unable to gather good enough info on it from other questions. But see, for example, [Writing a Default Constructor Forces Zero-Initialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27505539/writing-a-default-constructor-forces-zero-initialization).

The concrete problem I'm facing is: I want to make sure members of my classes are zeroed out both for (1) classes which declare a default c-tor, and for (2) those which don't.

For (2), initializing with `{}` does the job because it's the syntax for value-initialization, which translates to zero-initialization, or to aggregate initialization if your class is an aggregate - case in which members for which no initializer was provided (all!) are zero-initialized.

But for (1) I'm still not sure what would be the best approach. From all info I gather I learned that **if you provide a default c-tor (e.g. for setting some of the members to some values), you must explicitly zero remaining members, otherwise the syntax `MyClass c = MyClass();` or the C++11 `MyClass c{};` will not do the job**. In other words, value-initialization in this case means just calling your c-tor, and that's it (no zero-ing).

You run into the same situation if you declare a c-tor that takes values, and sets those values to a subset of the members, but you'd like other members to be zero-ed: there is no shorthand for doing it - I'm thinking about 3 options:

```
class MyClass
{
  int a;
  int b;
  int c;

  MyClass(int a)
  {
    this->a = a;
    // now b and c have indeterminate values, what to do? (before setting 'a')


    // option #1
    *this = MyClass{}; // we lost the ability to do this since it requires default c-tor which is inhibited by declaring this c-tor; even if we declare one (private), it needs to explicitly zero members one-by-one

    // option #2
    std::memset(this, 0, sizeof(*this)); // ugly C call, only works for PODs (which require, among other things, a default c-tor defaulted on first declaration)

    // option #3
    // don't declare this c-tor, but instead use the "named constructor idiom"/factory below
  }


  static MyClass create(int a)
  {
    MyClass obj{}; // will zero-initialize since there are no c-tors
    obj.a = a;
    return obj;
  }
};
```

Is my reasoning correct?
Which of the 3 options would *you* choose?

Comment: `class MyClass { int a = 0; int b = 0; int c = 0; /* your constructors */ };`. That can even be an aggregate since C++14.

Comment: *"even if we declare one (private), it needs to explicitly zero members one-by-one"* Not if you default it `= default`.

Comment: @dyp From what I know, the defaulted no-arg c-tor will not zero the members?

Comment: @haelix Yes, but it allows value-initialization to perform zero-initialization. That is, `MyClass obj{};` will zero-initialize `obj` if `MyClass`'s default ctor is defaulted.

Comment: @dyp that is very interesting for my case, I'll update the question because I need more info / exact source for that case

Comment: @haelix It is case 2) on cppreference: a defaulted default ctor is **not** user-provided. [dcl.fct.def.default]/5 "A function is user-provided if it is user-declared and not explicitly defaulted or
deleted on its first declaration."

Comment: Allright so you're referring to case 2) "(since C++14)" - that makes sense. What I'd like to know now - if you default the default c-tor on first declaration, thereby enabling value-initialization, is it possible to write another c-tor (with 1+ argument(s) ) and use `constructor delegation` to the defaulted c-tor in order to value-initialize? My guess is that zero-initialization will not happen in this case (in the sense that it's not guaranteed by  the standard).

Comment: Yes, it seems constructor delegation will not invoke value-initialization when delegating to the default constructor, but simply call that constructor. You can however achieve something similar by adding a layer of abstraction, i.e. `class MyClass { struct { int a; int b; int c; } data; public: MyClass() = default; MyClass(int a) : data() { data.a = a; } };`

Comment: @dyp Thanks for the comments. Would you care to write an answer that supports my `option #1` in conjunction with your arguments why (and when) that works. From all info I gather, that would be the preferred option in my specific case. So basically, add c-tor defaulted on first declaration, invoke that using `*this = MyClass{};`, and subsequently set your selected data members to what you'd like. Pity that we can't use c-tor delegation, since the solution now requires an assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my humble opinion, the simplest way to ensure zero-initialization is to add a layer of abstraction:

```
class MyClass
{
    struct
    {
        int a;
        int b;
        int c;
    } data{};
public:
    MyClass(int a) : data{a} {}
};
```

Moving the data members into a struct lets us use value-initialization to perform zero-initialization. Of course, it is now a bit more cumbersome to access those data members: `data.a` instead of just `a` within `MyClass`.
A default constructor for `MyClass` will perform zero-initialization of `data` and all its members because of the braced-initializer for `data`. Additionally, we can use aggregate-initialization in the constructors of `MyClass`, which also value-initializes those data members which are not explicitly initialized.

The downside of the indirect access of the data members can be overcome by using *inheritance* instead of *aggregation*:

```
struct my_data
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};

class MyClass : private my_data
{
    MyClass() : my_data() {}
public:
    MyClass(int a) : MyClass() { this->a = a; }
};
```

By explicitly specifying the base-initializer `my_data()`, value-initialization is invoked as well, leading to zero-initialization. This default constructor should probably be marked as `constexpr` and `noexcept`. Note that it is no longer trivial. We can use initialization instead of assignment by using aggregate-initialization or forwarding constructors:

```
class MyClass : private my_data
{
public:
    MyClass(int a) : my_data{a} {}
};
```

You can also write a wrapper template that ensures zero-initialization, thought the benefit is disputable in this case:

```
template<typename T>
struct zero_init_helper : public T
{
    zero_init_helper() : T() {}
};

struct my_data
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};

class MyClass : private zero_init_helper<my_data>
{
public:
    MyClass(int a) { this->a = a; }
};
```

Having a user-provided constructor, `zero_init_helper` no longer is an aggregate, hence we cannot use aggregate-initialization any more. To use initialization instead of assignment in the ctor of `MyClass`, we have to add a forwarding constructor:

```
template<typename T>
struct zero_init_helper : public T
{
    zero_init_helper() : T() {}

    template<typename... Args>
    zero_init_helper(Args&&... args) : T{std::forward<Args>(args)...} {}
};

class MyClass : private zero_init_helper<my_data>
{
public:
    MyClass(int a) : zero_init_helper(a) {}
};
```

Constraining the constructor template requires some `is_brace_constructible` trait, which is not part of the current C++ Standard. But this already is a ridiculously complicated solution to the problem.

---

It is also possible to implement your option #1 as follows:

```
class MyClass
{
  int a;
  int b;
  int c;

  MyClass() = default; // or public, if you like

public:
  MyClass(int a)
  {
    *this = MyClass{}; // the explicitly defaulted default ctor
                       // makes value-init use zero-init
    this->a = a;
  }
};
```

---

What about constructor delegation?

```
class MyClass
{
  int a;
  int b;
  int c;

  MyClass() = default; // or public, if you like

public:
  MyClass(int a) : MyClass() // ctor delegation
  {
      this->a = a;
  }
};
```

[class.base.init]/7 suggests that the above example shall invoke value-initialization, which leads to zero-initialization since the class does not have any user-*provided* default constructors [dcl.init]/8.2. Recent versions of clang++ seem to zero-initialize the object, recent versions of g++ do not. I've reported this as [g++ bug #65816](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65816).

Comment: Nice detailed answer, thanks. Maybe someone will add more useful thoughts regarding the last paragraph "constructor delegation" - that would be syntactically the best approach and something I believe the standard should offer.

Comment: @haelix I filed a g++ bug report.

Answer (score 4):

What about using in-class initialization?

```
class Foo
{
    int _a{}; // zero-it
    int _b{}; // zero-it
public:
    Foo(int a): _a(a){} // over-rules the default in-class initialization
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Option 4 and 5:

option 4:

```
MyClass(int a) :a(a), b(0), c(0)
  {
  }
```

option 5:

```
class MyClass
  {
      int a = 0;
      int b = 0;
      int c = 0;

      MyClass(int a) : a(a) {
      }
  }
```

Comment: I would be for one of those options. I think that option 5) looks the most error-prone.