# Why is this member variable not getting correctly initialized?

Tags: c++

Just stumbled on this, can anybody explain what is happening here?

```
struct Foo {
    int i;
    ~Foo() {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
};

void bar()
{
    Foo f;
    f.i = 1;
    f = Foo();
    f.i = 2;
}
```

I'm getting the following output:

```
-85899... (gibberish = "default" value for uninitialized int)
2
```

where I expected

```
1
2
```

Why is it that `f.i = 1;` seems to have no effect here?

Comment: Because the destructor for f doesn't get called when you assign a new Foo value to it.  The first output is probably from the destructor of the temporary in f = Foo().

Comment: @mfontanini There is no undefined behavior. The value of `i` when not initialized is indeterminate. The behavior is defined but not determinate. Two different things entirely.

Comment: Are you using an ancient compiler? Since 2003 (or possibly even 1998), `Foo()` should value-initialise the temporary, setting `i` to `0`.

Comment: @MikeSeymour I'm using VC10.

Comment: @Niko: So it's buggy rather than ancient. [Here's the bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/746973/).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `f.i = 1` does have an effect. It sets the member `i` to be equal to `1`. You'll only see that if the object is destroyed, since you output the value in the destructor.

In the line `f = Foo();`, you're creating a temporary `Foo` object, which has an `i` with indeterminate value and then assign it to the object `f`. This temporary object is destroyed at the end of the line, printing it its own indeterminate `i`. This is what gives you the `-85899...` output.

The indeterminate value is copied over to the object `f`, but then you overwrite its member `i` with the value `2`. At the end of `bar`, this object is destroyed and you see the output `2`.

Comment: I don't think there's any more that could possibly be said about the piece of code in the question!   +1

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that a reasonably modern, non-buggy compiler should value-intialise the temporary and print zero rather than garbage.

Comment: @MikeSeymour C++ will never value-initialize member variables with simple types unless you tell it to.  This is by design -- value-initializing them would take time, and C++ assumes that you don't care (and don't want to waste that time) unless you tell it otherwise.  In particular, the value is considered "indeterminate".

Comment: @EdwardLoper: No, by writing `Foo()`, you tell it to value-initialise the temporary (and thereby value-initialise its members). There's no way to create a default-initialised temporary.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Right you are -- I hadn't noticed that.  For anyone else who's interested in the details of why Mike is right, see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5999549/222329

Answer (score 11):

So, the variable being destroyed in the first call to the destructor is not `f`, but the temporary created by `Foo()`. Since you don't have a constructor, `i` has an indeterminate value. If you were to add a constructor that sets `i` to, say, 99999, then you would see that output from your destructor.

```
void bar()
{
    Foo f;    // Construct f of type Foo
    f.i = 1;   // Set i to 1 in f. 
    f = Foo();   // Construct a temporary Foo object, copy it to f, 
                // then destroy the temporary object. 
    f.i = 2;   // Set the newly copied f.i to 2. 
               // destroy f.
}
```

Comment: And what is the second line due to?

Comment: @Niko - the destructor of f at the end of your scope / program.

Answer (score 4):

this:

```
f = Foo();
```

creates a new object, and copy it. then this object got destoyed, at the end of this line, but it was not initialized at all. just copied.

Answer (score 2):

The first output is from the destructor called on the temporary. The default assignment operator does not call any destructor thus the one that would print `1` is never called.

Some code to illustrate that:

```
struct Foo {
  int i;
  // we emulate the default operator= generated by the compiler
  // no check for self-assignment
  Foo& operator=(const Foo& other) { this->i = other.i; } 
};

void bar() {
  F f;
  f.i = 1;
  f = Foo(); // the i member of the temporary is indeterminate
             // now f.i is indeterminate
             // destroy the temporary
  f.i = 2;  
} // end of scope, destroy f
```