# Why do I get random numbers after the input?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to take in some input and find the number of a certain character in a string. I keep getting a weird answer when I try to take in the actual string. Why is this happening?
I'm using cout to find why I'm getting such weird numbers and it appears to be a problem with the input.

Note - This is my attempted solution to Codeforces Problem 462 B. I'm attempting to just find the number of a certain letter in the input. My friend is attempting a bubble sort method.

Input:

```
6 4
YJSNPI
```

Expected Output:

```
YJSNPI
4
```

Actual Output:

```
YJSNPI
1699623981
```

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <istream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n, k, counting;
    cin >> n >>k;
    char trash;
    cin.get(trash);
    vector<string> cards;
    string theline, name;
    cin >> theline;
    cout << theline << "\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        name = theline[i];
        cards.push_back(name);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        if (cards[i] == cards[k-1]){
            counting++;
        }
    }
    int tmp = 0;
    if (cards.size() != k){
        tmp = k - counting;
    }
    counting *= k;
    counting += tmp;
    cout << counting;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe your compiler can help. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aa76f26a2889c724

Answer (score 4):

Local variables are not automatically initialized to `0`. If you try to use the value of a local variable before assigning it, you get undefined behavior. You're incrementing `counting` without ever initializing it. Change to:

```
int n, k, counting = 0;
```

Comment: The code works now. I'm not getting the right answer but that's more a problem with my solution than anything else. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that the variable "counting" is never initialized - [handy link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032638/default-variable-value)

Basically, "counting" has some garbage value from memory after you declare it with

```
int counting;
```

Then, the first operation performed is

```
counting++;
```

And the garbage value is saved.

THE FIX:

Change

```
int counting;
```

to

```
int counting = 0;
```

NOTE: n and k are not helpful variable names. It would make understanding the code a lot easier if they had real names, but oh well.

ADDITIONALLY:
As chris mentioned above, make the compiler work for you. See comment below for good compiler flags. Don't ignore warnings!

Comment: `-Wall` is only `-Wsome`; it leaves out many warnings. To really get a lot of warnings, you should use `-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -std=c++11`.

Answer (score 0):

Can't really understand what you are doing here.  But I can see where you are going wrong.

int n, k, counting;

counting is uninitialized try

int n, k, counting = 0;

I get answer of (1*4 + 4 - 1) = 7 not the 4 you are expecting.

This code will always result in counting = 1, given that k is within range.

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    if (cards[i] == cards[k-1]){
        counting++;
    }
}
```

https://ideone.com/7Hk3ix