# How can I fix my issue with my nested for loop program?

Tags: c++, for-loop, nested-loops

The end of my program is supposed to show the amount of ways I can make change for a dollar using nickels, dimes, quarters, and fifty-cents. Whenever I run my program, it gives me a really huge number and I don't know why. It's supposed to be around 40 something ( I estimate) but instead whenever I run it I get like 2686964 ways. This is my program:

```css
//Program to display the number of ways to make change for a dollar
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
 int nickels,dimes,quarts,fifcents,way;
 double totalCents;
 cout<<setw(8)<<"Nickels"<<setw(7)<<"Dimes"<<setw(9)<<"Quarters"<<setw(12)<<"Fifty-Cents"<<endl;
 for(nickels=0;nickels<=20;nickels++)
 {
  for(dimes=0;dimes<=10;dimes++)
  {
   for(quarts= 0; quarts<=4; quarts++)
   {
    for(fifcents = 0; fifcents <=2; fifcents++)
    {
    
        totalCents=(nickels*5)+(dimes*10)+(quarts*25)+(fifcents*50);
        if(totalCents==100)
        {
              cout<<setw(5)<<nickels<<setw(7)<<dimes<<setw(7)<<quarts<<setw(10)<<fifcents<<endl; 
            way++;    
        }
       }
      }
     }
    }
    cout<<"There are "<<way<<" ways to make change for a dollar using using nickels, dimes, quarters and fifty-cents."<<endl;
}
```

Comment: "*It's supposed to be around 40 something*" — have you tried **roughly** doing it on paper? Turning groups of five ones in { 1, 1, 1, ... , 1, 1, 1 } to single fives, there are **20** ways. Similarly, there are **10** ways of changing { 1, 1, 1, ... , 1, 1, 1 } into tens, **5** ways to turn it into twenties, and **2** ways of turning it into fifties. That's 37 right there. 40 sounds **way** too low an estimate - I just showed how to do it with only two types of coins.

Comment: Not sure I understand why you chose to format your C++ code using HTML snippet tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize way with 0, that means, assign 0 to it at the beginning of the program `way = 0;` uninitialized variables may contain any content when declared

Comment: What do you mean by initializing way with 0? Writing a for loop for way?

Comment: Aditionally, take a look at the answer to this other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032638/default-variable-value it explains why your program actually had undefined behavior and could give different outputs for different executions over the same input