# Project Euler #8 Largest product in a series

Tags: c++

I am working on Project Euler's problem #8 in which I am asked to "Find the thirteen adjacent digits in this 1000-digit number that have the greatest product. What is the value of this product?"

Here is my C++ code. For some reason, it keeps giving me the wrong answer and I strongly suspect that it has something do do with me using wrong data types. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
{
    int n = 0;
    unsigned long long x, y;
    signed char num[] = "7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";
    while(n <= 1000)
    {
        x = (num[n] - 48) * (num[n + 1] - 48) * (num[n + 2] - 48) * (num[n + 3] - 48) * (num[n + 4] - 48) * (num[n + 5] - 48) * (num[n + 6] - 48) * (num[n + 7] - 48) * (num[n + 8] - 48) * (num[n + 9] - 48) * (num[n + 10] - 48) * (num[n + 11] - 48) * (num[n + 12] - 48);
        std::cout << "x" << x << std::endl;
        if(x > y)
        {
            y = x;
        }
        n = n + 1;
    }
    std::cout << "y" << y << std::endl;
    std::cout << "n" << n << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: [OT]: use `'0'` instead of magic number `48`.

Comment: What do you think the initial value of `y` is? Also, `while (n < 1000 - 12)`

Comment: You need to initialize y and you are going past the end of the array of digits.

Comment: Is the correct answer supposed to be "18446744073195294960"?

Comment: 23514624000 is the correct answer

Comment: @ElliottFrisch when a variable is initialized, doesn't it by default have a value of 0? Or am I not understanding it correctly?

Comment: @Sonarbuddy `int y;` is UB. It could be `0`, or it could be anything. So, in short; [not necessarily](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032638/default-variable-value).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One major problem as pointed in the other answer, is that your result will be taken as `int`, exceeding the maximum value of `Int32` leading to the wrong answer.Your while will iterate 1 extra index too.The line where you calculate `x` can be done much better currently it's hard to follow what's going on and it's hard to maintain.

I recommend first creating a *constant* integer which will have the value of the desired adjacent digits in your case 13.

```
const int adjacentDigits = 13;
```

This should do the job now you should also fix the `while` loop :

```
while (n <= 1000 - adjacentDigits)
```

Here we use the const we declared earlier so if we want the code to work for a different amount of adjacent digits we can simply just change the variable responsive for that.

You should give a starting value to `y`

```
unsigned long long y = 0;
```

Now going into the while loop we see the long line I spoke of earlier. We can easily edit this to something like :

```
    for (int i = n; i < n + adjacentDigits; i++)
    {
        x *= (num[i] - '0');
    }
```

This is much easier to read and it will remove the use of casting. Now one problem with your current set up your variable 'x' is declared in the outer scope (outside of the loop), and here rather than just setting the variable value we are multiplying it which means we need to reset the variable back to 0 once we are done multiplying. There are 2 ways that you can do this you can either set it to zero at the end of the loop or simply declare it in the while loop which I prefer. It's also important to put the value of `x` to 1 instead of 0..

```
unsigned long long x = 1;
```

After this we simply keep your original check that determines whether we have found a new number.

```
if (x > y)
{
    y = x;
}
```

At the end we just print `y`

Here's the full code :

```
const int adjacentDigits = 13;
int n = 0;
unsigned long long y = 0;
signed char num[] = "7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";
while (n <= 1000 - adjacentDigits)
{
    unsigned long long x = 1;
    for (int i = n; i < n+ adjacentDigits; i++)
    {
        x *= (num[i] - '0');
    }
    if (x > y)
    {
        y = x;
    }
    n++;
}
std::cout << y << std::endl;
```

You might also want to use a little bit more reasonable names `x` and `y` sound a little bit like variables that are used in a grid.. For example You can simply change `y` to `maxNumber` and `y` to `tempNumber`.

Comment: Ohh thank you so much. I was not resetting x between each iteration. That is immensely helpful.

Answer (score 2):

First, you haven't initialized y like others said in the comment.

Second, this expression `(num[n] - 48) * (num[n + 1] - 48) * (num[n + 2] - 48) * ...` will be done in `int` precision, because types smaller than int will be promoted to int before doing arithmetics

Change it to

```
x = (unsigned long long)(num[n] - '0') * (num[n + 1] - '0') * ...
```

so that the expresion is calculated in `unsigned long long` precision. Use '0' instead of 48 because it says the intention more clearly and it'll work regardless of `'0'`'s value

You also have out of bound access when n >= 1000-12. Use `for` instead

```
int len = strlen(num);
for (n = 0; n < len - 12; n++)
```

You can improve it further if you recognize there's some overlap when calculating the product in each iteration

Comment: If you want to know the position of these 13 numbers, you have to write `n` to a variable each time you write `y=x` e.g. `m=n`. And then print out `m` instead of `n` at the end

Comment: Thank you very much. I am just learning about the different data types and when to use each one.

Answer (score 0):

Thought I'd share my solution as well as one answer requested other Scala solutions. I'm not saying this is in any way better, just a slightly different approach. Also, I think `String.substring()` is slow (linear time complexity), so I decided to not use it.

Also includes a small optimization with handling of zeroes that wasn't discussed by other answers: if there is a 0 in the next (13) digits, we can skip over all these digits since the 0 will be included in their ranges as well.

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec

object Problem8 extends App {
  val input = """
    73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934
    96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843
    85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511
    12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557
    66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113
    62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749
    30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866
    70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776
    65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243
    52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397
    53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482
    83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474
    82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881
    16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586
    17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042
    24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408
    07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188
    84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606
    05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725
    71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450
  """

  val digits = input.filterNot(_.isWhitespace).map(_.asDigit)

  //  val adjacentDigits = 4
  val adjacentDigits = 13

  @tailrec
  def largestProduct(digits: Seq[Int],
                     largestSoFar: BigInt,
                     previousWasZero: Boolean
                    ): BigInt = {
    digits.take(adjacentDigits) match {
      case Nil        => largestSoFar
      case nextDigits =>
        val product = nextDigits.foldLeft(BigInt(1))(_ * _)
        if (product.equals(BigInt(0))) {
          val indexOfZero = if (previousWasZero) nextDigits.indexOf(0) else adjacentDigits - 1
          largestProduct(digits.drop(indexOfZero + 1), largestSoFar, true)
        } else {
          val largest = if (product > largestSoFar) product else largestSoFar
          largestProduct(digits.tail, largest, false)
        }
    }
  }

  println(largestProduct(digits, BigInt(0), true))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved that with Golang, actually what I did was read the series from both  sides left and right (start and end of string) to gain a little of performance:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {

    numberOfAdjacentElements := 13
    series := `7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450`

    higher := findGreatestProductInSeries(series, numberOfAdjacentElements)

    fmt.Printf("Product is %v\n", higher)
}

func greater(a, b int) int {

    higher := b

    if a > b {
        higher = a
    }

    return higher
}

func calculateProduct(numbers []int) int {

    product := 1

    for _, number := range numbers {
        product *= number
    }

    return product
}

func findGreatestProductInSeries(series string, numberOfAdjacentElements int) int {

    higher := 0
    length := len(series)

    for index := 0; index < (length/2)-numberOfAdjacentElements; index++ {

        frontArr := []int{}
        tailArr := []int{}

        for row := index; row < index+numberOfAdjacentElements; row++ {
            front, frontError := strconv.Atoi(string(series[row]))
            tail, tailError := strconv.Atoi(string(series[length-1-row]))

            if frontError == nil {
                frontArr = append(frontArr, front)
            } else {
                fmt.Println(frontError)
            }

            if tailError == nil {
                tailArr = append(tailArr, tail)
            }
        }

        startProduct := calculateProduct(frontArr)
        endProduct := calculateProduct(tailArr)
        greatest := greater(startProduct, endProduct)

        if greatest > higher {
            higher = greatest
        }
    }

    return higher
}
```