# Implicit variable initialization in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int a;
void foo();

int main() 
{
 std::cout << "a = " << a << std::endl;
 foo();
 return 0;
}

void foo(){
    int b;
    std::cout << "b = " << b << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
a = 0
b = 32650
```

I have created a function named `foo` that declares a `int` variable and prints it. It prints some junk value because `b` is not initialized at the time of declaration then how is `a` getting initialized to `0` everytime?

Why is `a` initialized to `0` while `b` being initialized to some junk value?

Comment: `a` is initialized to 0 because it is a global variable, and all the global variables are implicitly initialized with 0

Comment: @juanchopanza No, only `a` is getting initialized to `0` just because it is globally defined.

Comment: Global variables are auto initialized to zeros at startup.  Local variables are not auto initialized at all (unless they are a class/struct type that has a default constructor)

Comment: Note that observing that a variable prints `0` doesn't necessarily mean it's initialized. Reading uninitialized variables is undefined behavior and may very well also print `0`. Learning c++ by trying and observing (or trial-and-error) can be misleading as observed behavior may have nothing to do with the code if it contains undefined behavior.

Comment: So this is a general rule in C++?

Comment: @SaifUrRahman Ah yes, I thought you were printing `c`.

Comment: @juanchopanza Sorry about that `c`. I'll remove that.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux So, is it printing `0` just because it is an undefined behaviour at the time of reading the variable `a` inside printing statement or the zero value is assigned at the time of declaration. (for global variables)?

Comment: "It prints some junk value because b is not initialized" - It's worse than that. Reading an uninitialized variable is Undefined Behaviour and if your program contains UB the compiler is free to generate *whatever code it likes*, and not just for the access of that variable, but for *all* of your program. So by reading that uninitialized variable you've basically thrown all possibilities of reasoning about *any* part of your program into the trash. And yes, modern compilers do heavily exploit UB. Don't write code with UB.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Default variable value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032638/default-variable-value)

Comment: @SaifUrRahman In this case, `a` is initialized to zero. Though printing `b` might also print zero, it could print anything or do something entirely different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From draft of c++17 standard (other standards states almost the same):

> 3.6.2  Initialization of non-local variables [basic.start.init]
>
> ...
>
> Variables with **static storage** duration (3.7.1) or thread storage duration (3.7.2) shall be **zero-initialized** (8.5) before any other initialization takes place.
>
> ...
>
> 3.7.1  Static storage duration [basic.stc.static]
>
> ...
>
> All variables which do not have dynamic storage duration, do not have thread storage duration, and are
> not local have
> static storage duration
> .  The storage for these entities shall **last for the duration of the
> program** (3.6.2, 3.6.3).

If you will go deep into definitions, you will find that `a` is actually has static storage duration (it is global variable) and therefore it is zero-initialized.

Answer (score 3):

In the original version of C++ language standard, all variables with *static storage duration* were zero-initialized before any other initialization took place.

In modern C++ this initialization stage (aka *static initialization*) is split into *constant initialization* (for variables with explicit constant initializers) and *zero initialization* (for everything else). Your `a` falls into the second category. So your `a` is zero-initialized.

Automatic variables of non-class types, like your `b`, begin their life with indeterminate values, unless you initialize them explicitly. Using that indeterminate value in an expression leads to undefined behavior.