# Default value of static std::unordered_map

Tags: c++, dictionary, static, initialization

I would like to know the default value of variables inside a struct of static `static std::unordered_map<std::string, struct>`.

Here's my example code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

int main()
{
    enum MyStateType
    {
        MY_STATE_NEW,
        MY_STATE_RUN,
        MY_STATE_FREE
    };
    struct Foo
    {
        int num;
        MyStateType state;
    };
    static std::unordered_map<std::string, Foo> map;

    std::cout << map["Apple"].num << '\n';
    std::cout << map["Apple"].state << '\n';
}
```

The output result:

```
0
0
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Is it safe to think that variables inside `Foo` are always initialized to `0` in the beginning?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization

Comment: Don't use [`operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_at) with the STL map containers.  They construct the value if it is not present.  Use [`.at()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/at) instead.

Comment: Yes, in this case it's safe, and in-fact mandated by the standard. New items added to both `std::map` and `std::unordered_map` via the array index `operator[]` are *value-initialized*. Barring user-defined construction (where you're responsible for member-initializing) a trivial type such as yours will most-definitely be zero-filled.

Comment: @BenjaminBarrois No, that is wrong.  [`operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_at) will default-construct the element which in this case value-initializes the members to zero.  “When the default allocator is used, this results in the key being copy constructed from key and the mapped value being value-initialized.”

Comment: @HenriMenke Look at the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032638/default-variable-value
Thinking everything is zero-initialized is in general a bad idea though this is sometimes true. This definitely can lead to different behaviors depending on what standard and compiler you are using.

Comment: @BenjaminBarrois I'm not saying everything will always be zero initialized but in case of [`operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_at) for `std::unordered_map` the standard *guarantees* value initialization.

Comment: @BenjaminBarrois that link is unrelated, and discusses a completely different situation. The OP is not asking about a naked variable declaration; he's asking about variables constructed as  the tuple-second in an association container as a result of `operator[]` usage. The standard has very specific, clear rules about what happens in that case, and  further places specific conditions on the object type. Ex: it must be default-constructible, for example, either user-provided or implementation-default.  When the object is constructed `T()` is used. Those `()` are important. See [dcl.init].

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes, it is actually safe to assume that the values inside `Foo` are always initialized to zero because of the behaviour of [`operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_at)

> When the default allocator is used, this results in the key being copy/move constructed from key and the mapped value being value-initialized.

You do not provide a constructor which means that each field in `Foo` will be value initialized individually which for primitive types means zero initialization.

## but

The problem you are actually facing here is that a field called `"Apple"` does not exist in your map.  Unfortunately the semantics of `operator[]` are such that if the value does not exist, it will be created on the fly.  You probably didn't even want to access a non-existent field in the map and you are asking whether it is always initialized to zero so that you can use this fact to check whether the element was there.  For this purpose however, you should either use the [`find()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/find) or [`at()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/at) member function.

- `find()` will return an iterator pointing to the end of the map if the element does not exist.  That means you could guards the element access using

  ```
  if (auto apple = map.find("Apple"); apple != map.end()) {
      std::cout << apple->second.num << '\n';
      std::cout << apple->second.state << '\n';
  }
  ```

  (with the C++17 `if` statement initializer)
- `at()` will throw an exception if the element is not found.

  ```
  std::cout << map.at("Apple").num << '\n';
  std::cout << map.at("Apple").state << '\n';
  ```

  This will crash your program with a `std::out_of_range` exception.  You might feel temped to catch this exception to check whether the element existed.  Don't do this.  It is very bad practice to use exceptions for control flow.  On top of that exception are dead slow when they are being thrown.

Comment: Thank you very much Sir.

Comment: @ZackLee I added some details.