# difference between int x and int x=0 in C++

Tags: c++, types

I was taught that when I declare a type "int x" the default value of it will be 0, but when I try to print it or make "x+=10" it shows some random numbers(maybe memory point). But everything works fine when I type "int x=0;" and "x+=10" the answer is 10. So what is a difference between 
`int x;`
and
`int x=0;`
?

Comment: Who taught you that there is a default value for `int` in C++?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032638/default-variable-value

Comment: *"I was taught that when I declare a type "int x" the default value of it will be 0"* - whoever taught you this was wrong (for primitive types).

Comment: The sentence should be: _"when I declare a non-local variable "int x" the default value of it will be 0"_ It doesn't work with local variables.

Comment: If it is a global variable it will be 0. A local variable will have a garbage value. That garbage value may even be 0 the first time you run your function tricking you into believing that your compiler is setting it to 0. The reason for this is your OS may give memory pages to your program that is filled with 0s to avoid leaking sensitive information from the last program that used the same physical memory.

Answer (score 0):

The default value is not guaranteed to be zero when you declare it. If residual information exists on the area where the program was loaded, you may experience surprises. 
When you also initialize its value, then you have the guarantee that the variable has the value you expect.