# Writing text on heap - what does this mean? x[count++] = c;

Tags: c++

I'm studying a code that writes text on the heap:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    
    char c;
    int count{0},d{0};
    char *x;
    x = new char[1000];
    if(x != NULL){
        cout << "enter the text,ending with by eof marker" << endl;
        for(count=0; count!=cin.eof()&&count<1000;){
            cin >> c;
            if(!cin.eof())
            x[count++] = c;
                
        }
        for(int d=0; d<count;d++)
        cout << *(x+d);
        cout << "end of text" << endl;
    }
```

I have a problem understanding this snippet:

```cpp
x[count++] = c;
```

Can anyone explain it to me?

Comment: `x[count++] = c;` is equivalent to `x[count] = c; count = count + 1;`.

Comment: I would be wary of wherever you got that code from. This is far from an example of good C++ code. Checking if `new` returns `NULL`, comparing `cin.eof()` with an int, declaring two variables named `d` and only using one---none of this makes any sense.

Comment: Particularly, there is a memory leak (missing `delete[] x`) and `count != cin.eof()` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: thank you guys, this is actually from my professor's solution!

Comment: @jujubeefei then your professor is teaching you bad C++. There are a lot of mistakes in this code.

Comment: This may be the *worst* possible way to read a string from the console. Also, fix your indentation. It'll save you headaches in the future. I'd ask your prof why you're using C-style strings in C++, and why you're providing initializers for types that are default initialized to 0. That typically only happens when Java people decided that they're C programmers. Everything about this solution is wrong except that it *happens* to work, despite the author's best efforts.

Comment: The integers would be uninitialized if no initializer were provided: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032638/default-variable-value

Comment: This code could be simplified a lot, for example: `cin.read(x, 1000);`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is doing a [post-increment](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_incdec) of `count`. The value of `c` will be assigned to `x[i]`, where `i` is the **old** value of `count`.

It's equivalent to:

```
x[count] = c;
count = count + 1;
```

Comment: Hi jtbandes, thanks for your help. I agree with you that count != can.eof() doesn't make sense.So, what is the correct way to rewrite this snippet code?

Comment: Well, `cin.eof()`  is a bool so you could just delete the `count !=`. On the other hand, the `if` inside the loop is already checking for eof, so you could add `else { break; }`.

Comment: @jujubeefei An alternative: `while (count < 1000 & cin >> c) { x[count++] = c; }` In English, While we still have space in the array and we successfully read a character from the input stream, store the character in the array and increase the counter by 1.

Comment: @user4581301 I think you meant `&&` :)

Comment: Smurf. I'm writing that off as a typo.