# How to calculate inputted values using a while loop c++?

Tags: c++, while-loop, addition

How do you use a **while loop only** to add multiple values with a given point when to exit the loop and display the tallied amounts.

Note the following example. **Test  your  program by  entering  7 for the  number  of items  and the  following  values  for  the  calories:** 7 - 120 60 150 600 1200 300 200

If your  logic is correct, the following  will be  displayed: **Total calories eaten today = 2630**

Below is what I have written, what I require is understanding the calculation for the total calories.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int numberOfItems;
    int count = 1; //loop counter for the loop
    int caloriesForItem;
    int totalCalories;
    cout << "How many items did you eat today? ";
    cin >> numberOfItems;
    cout << "Enter the number of calories in each of the "
         << numberOfItems << " items eaten:  " << endl;

    while (count <= numberOfItems) // count cannot be more than the number of items
    {
        cout << "Enter calorie: ";
        cin >> caloriesForItem;
        totalCalories = ; //?
        ++count;
    }
    cout << "Total calories  eaten today  = " << totalCalories;

    return 0;
}
```

How do I store a value, then add on that value, repeatedly until the program reaches a point to exit as per the count value

Comment: Why is "**Total calories eaten today = 2631**"? It adds up to `2630`.

Comment: You could move the declaration of `caloriesForItem` to inside the `while` loop, as the first statement.  This is a practice you may want to build up: declaring variables closest to their first usage.  Also, that variable is only used within the `while` loop.

Comment: @PalLaden the 2631 was a typo, apologies, I have since corrected the error upon your noticing of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Logic Explained

- Initialize `totalCalories` to `0` outside the loop. *This is required to prevent [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).* You may refer to [(Why) is using an uninitialized variable undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11962457/why-is-using-an-uninitialized-variable-undefined-behavior) and [Default variable value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032638/default-variable-value).
- For every item, add `caloriesForItem` to `totalCalories`. *You may also use the [+= operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_assignment) if you are familiar with it.*

### Sourcecode

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int numberOfItems;
    int count = 1; //loop counter for the loop
    int caloriesForItem;
    long totalCalories = 0;
    cout << "How many items did you eat today? ";
    cin >> numberOfItems;
    cout << "Enter the number of calories in each of the "
         << numberOfItems << " items eaten: " << endl;

    while (count <= numberOfItems) // count cannot be more than the number of items
    {
        cout << "Enter calorie: ";
        cin >> caloriesForItem;
        totalCalories = totalCalories + caloriesForItem;
        ++count;
    }
    cout << "Total calories eaten today  = " << totalCalories;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @PalLaden, this [int totalCalories = 0;] made all the difference. And for explaining the reasoning, I have a much more conscience understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can add them with += operator. But the result will be the same.

```
totalCalories += caloriesForItem;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should increase the number of total calories in every loop. You can easily do that using the addition assignment operator (+=). It should look like this :

```
totalCalories += caloriesForItem;
```