# Is there a compile-time func/macro to determine if a C++0x struct is POD?

Tags: c++, type-traits, static-assert, c++11

I'd like to have a C++0x [static_assert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293588.aspx) that tests whether a given struct type is [POD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178175/what-are-aggregates-and-pods-and-how-why-are-they-special) (to prevent other programmers from inadvertently breaking it with new members). ie,

```
struct A // is a POD type
{
   int x,y,z;
}

struct B // is not a POD type (has a nondefault ctor)
{
   int x,y,z; 
   B( int _x, int _y, int _z ) : x(_x), y(_y), z(_z) {}
}

void CompileTimeAsserts()
{
  static_assert( is_pod_type( A ) , "This assert should not fire." );
  static_assert( is_pod_type( B ) , "This assert will fire and scold whoever added a ctor to the POD type." );
}
```

Is there some kind of `is_pod_type()` macro or intrinsic that I can use here? I couldn't find one in any C++0x docs, but of course the web's info on 0x is still rather fragmentary.

Comment: Note that in C++0x, struct B is not POD because it does not have a *trivial default constructor* (see 9.0.10 and 9.0.6 in N3242). I'm not sure what exactly counts as a trivial default constructor (see 12.1.5), but suspect that adding `B() = default;` might turn struct B into a C++0x POD.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

C++0x introduces a type traits library in the header `<type_traits>` for this sort of introspection, and there is an `is_pod` type trait.  I believe that you would use it in conjunction with `static_assert` as follows:

```
static_assert(std::is_pod<A>::value, "A must be a POD type.");
```

I'm using ISO draft N3092 for this, so there's a chance that this is out of date.  I'll go look this up in the most recent draft to confirm it.

**EDIT**: According to the most recent draft ([N3242](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf)) this is still valid.  Looks like this is the way to do it!

Comment: Note that in C++0x, the POD definition has been relaxed and split up. So there is now also `std::is_trivially_copyable<>` and `std::is_standard_layout<>` (see the linked N3242). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6496545/trivial-vs-standard-layout-vs-pod/6496703#6496703 for what *trivially copyable* and *standard layout* mean.

Comment: Also, `is_pod` was introduced in TR1 for C++03 (or, technically, in [Boost.TypeTraits](http://www.boost.org/libs/type_traits/index.html) before that) -- it's only been made _standard_ in C++0x.