# Is this struct POD in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11

Is this struct a POD in C++11?

```
struct B
{
  int a;
  B(int aa) : a(aa) {}
  B() = default;
};
```

Note that this question is explicit about **C++11**. I know that this class is not a POD in C++98 nor C++03.

For an explanation of POD in C++11, see [trivial vs. standard layout vs. POD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6496545/trivial-vs-standard-layout-vs-pod/6496703#6496703)

(Inspired by this question: [Is there a compile-time func/macro to determine if a C++0x struct is POD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7169131/is-there-a-compile-time-func-macro-to-determine-if-a-c0x-struct-is-pod) )

Comment: ...What class are you referring to?

Comment: Honestly, if you saw the question about `std::is_pod`, *why didn't you ask this to a compiler*?

Comment: @R. Martinho Fernandes VS2010 didn't accept the "=default", nor did the Comeau online compiler.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, it is a POD according to the [new rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178175/what-are-aggregates-and-pods-and-how-why-are-they-special/7189821#7189821).

If you look up paragraph §8.4.2/4 of the new standard, you can see that if a constructor is defaulted on the first declaration, it is not user-provided:

> Explicitly-defaulted functions and implicitly-declared functions are
>   collectively called *defaulted* functions, and the implementation shall
>   provide implicit definitions for them (§12.1 §12.4, §12.8), which might
>   mean defining them as deleted. A special member function is
>   *user-provided* if it is user-declared and not explicitly defaulted or
>   deleted on its first declaration. (...)

You can use the `std::is_pod` type trait to have the compiler [test this](http://ideone.com/vCN9q) for you with `static_assert`.

```
static_assert(std::is_pod<B>::value, "B should be a POD");
```

Comment: I don't trust compilers to get this right yet. In fact, I couldn't even find a compiler that would compile my code without choking on the `= default` part!

Comment: GCC 4.5 supports that, and that's what's running behind ideone.com. Sometimes I forget that not every other compiler is at the same level of support of C++11 features :(

Comment: Thanks for the quote, it was the missing link for me. A default constructor is not trivial if it is user-provided, and your quote makes it clear that the `B() = default;` does not count as user-provided.

Comment: @Sjoerd: don't forget that `= default` must appear on the first declaration (which will be inside the class). It is not trivial if you declare `B();` in the class and then do `B::B() = default;`.