# Default constructor/destructor outside the class?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, destructor, default-constructor

Is the following legal according to the C++11 standard (`= default` outside the definition of the class) ?

```
// In header file
class Test
{
    public:
        Test();
        ~Test();
};

// In cpp file
Test::Test() = default;
Test::~Test() = default;
```

Comment: This is fine, the standard even uses it in an example (`§8.4.2/3`). `= default` and `= delete` are just "normal" function bodies (as per spec, anyways), i.e. what you'd write in a *definition*.

Comment: Note that a defaulted definition can appear after the first declaration of the function while a deleted definition has to be the first declaration of the function.

Comment: @Xeo Sounds like an answer.

Comment: Note that a constructor that is defaulted in this way, is still a user-provided constructor. As a result, your class `Test` is not a trivial class. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/7169675/396551

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, a special member function can be default-defined out-of-line in a .cpp file.  Realize that by doing so, some of the properties of an inline-defaulted function will not apply to your class.  For example, if your copy constructor is default-defined out-of-line, your class will not be considered trivially copyable (which also disqualifies it from being recognized as a POD).  Similarly, a default-defined out-of-line destructor will disqualify your type from being trivial (or POD).

This can be useful if you wish to have a non-inline copy-constructor and control over where it is defined (perhaps to take control over generated template definitions it will require), but don't wish to manually define it yourself with a hand-crafted member-initializer list, which would be laborious and could go stale under maintenance.