# Initialise base class which is POD struct

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++11, constructor

Due to some legacy C code, I have the following POD `struct` defining 2D coordinates; and a C++ `class` inheriting from it in order to provide various operations:

```
struct coord
{
  double x;
  double y;
};

class CoordClass : public coord
{
  // Contains functions like...
  const CoordClass& operator+=(const CoordClass& rhs)
  {
    x += rhs.x;
    y += rhs.y;
    return *this;
  }

  double Magnitude() const { return std::sqrt(x*x + y*y); }
};
```

At present, `CoordClass` defines a constructor:

```
CoordClass(double xx, double yy) { x = xx; y = yy; }
```

Given `x` and `y` are members of the POD base `struct coord`, is it possible to write that constructor as an initialiser list and empty body instead? Answers considering both C++03 and C++11 interest me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++11 you can provide this constructor:

```
 CoordClass(double x, double y) : coord{x, y} {}
```

In C++03 is also possible to get an empty constructor body but I don't think it's worth doing:

```
CoordClass(double x, double y) : coord(make_coord(x, y)) {}
```

where `make_coord` is:

```
coord make_coord(double x, double y) {
    coord c = { x, y };
    return c;
}
```

It can be a `private static` method of `CoordClass`. Alternatively, it can be a free function which is `static` and/or a member of an anonymous namespace of `CoordClass.cpp`.

Answer (score 1):

In C++11, if you define a defaulted default constructor to a struct, it can still be a POD in C++11. (See [Is this struct POD in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7169658/is-this-struct-pod-in-c11) )

```
struct coord
{
  double x;
  double y;

  coord() = default;
  coord(double xx, double yy) : x(xx), y(yy) {}
};
```

Now the CoordClass constructor becomes easy:

```
CoordClass(double x, double y) : coord(x, y) {}
```

Comment: Ah! And, while I can't use `= default;` (MSVC), I think a similar struct with user-defined default constructor is still _standard-layout_? And thus, so long as the constructors are `#ifdef __cplusplus` guarded, it should interoperate fine?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
CoordClass(double xx, double yy) : coord { xx, yy } {}
```