# Why is std::string a standard layout type?

Tags: c++, c++11

Taking the example from here: [trivial vs. standard layout vs. POD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6496545/trivial-vs-standard-layout-vs-pod)

The following code passes:

```
struct T {
public:
    int i;
private:
    int j;
};

static_assert(! std::is_standard_layout<T>::value, "");
```

Yet the following does not:

```
static_assert(! std::is_standard_layout<std::string>::value, "");
```

So if all it takes for a type not to be a standard layout, then how could std::string possible be one?

Comment: "So if all it takes for a type not to be a standard layout" .. if it takes what? to not be  standard layout?

Comment: I don't think the standard guarantees this?

Comment: This is kind of an odd question, with a weak premise. First you don't identify what you find evidently "simple" about `T` ("all it takes") and then you don't explain why you think it should be so outlandish that `std::string` have some property that `T` doesn't.

Answer (score 9):

Let's look at the *actual* rules for standard layout:

> `[C++14: 9/7]:` A standard-layout class is a class that:
>
> - has no non-static data members of type non-standard-layout class (or array of such types) or reference,
> - has no virtual functions (10.3) and no virtual base classes (10.1),
> - **has the same access control (Clause 11) for all non-static data members**,
> - has no non-standard-layout base classes,
> - either has no non-static data members in the most derived class and at most one base class with non-static data members, or has no base classes with non-static data members, and
> - has no base classes of the same type as the first non-static data member.

`std::string` probably has no `public` data members (what would they be?), which is where you tripped up with your `T` (since now you have both `private` and `public` data members; see emboldened passage).

But as far as I can tell there is no actual requirement for `std::string` to be standard layout. That's just how your implementation has done it.

Comment: By the way, a little treat for "struct vs class" wrong'uns: _"9/7: A standard-layout struct is a standard-layout class defined with the class-key struct or the class-key class."_ i.e. literally exactly the same dang thing

Comment: Gotta love the standard for the clarity it provides for struct and class

Answer (score 2):

According to the requirement of [StandardLayoutType](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/StandardLayoutType):

> Requirements
>
> - All non-static data members have the same access control
> - ...

That's why `T` failed to be standard layout type. `std::string` is just satisfying the requirements.