# Trivial class that is not standard layout and vice versa

Tags: c++, c++11, standard-layout, trivially-copyable

What's an example of a C++ class that is a Trivial class but is not a Standard Layout class?

And vice versa? (A Standard Layout class that is not a Trivial class).

Comment: The first link has an excellent answer with examples, here's a link directly to the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6496703/4641116

Comment: @Eljay ah perfect, thanks. I had missed that.