# C++ dynamically allocated memory

Tags: c++, memory-management

I don't quite get the point of dynamically allocated memory and I am hoping you guys can make things clearer for me.

First of all, every time we allocate memory we simply get a pointer to that memory.

```
int * dynInt = new int;
```

So what is the difference between doing what I did above and:

```
int someInt;
int* dynInt = &someInt;
```

As I understand, in both cases memory is allocated for an int, and we get a pointer to that memory.

So what's the difference between the two. When is one method preferred to the other.

Further more why do I need to free up memory with

```
delete dynInt;
```

in the first case, but not in the second case.

My guesses are:

1. When dynamically allocating memory for an object, the object doesn't get initialized while if you do something like in the second case, the object get's initialized. If this is the only difference, is there a any motivation behind this apart from the fact that dynamically allocating memory is faster.
2. The reason we don't need to use delete for the second case is because the fact that the object was initialized creates some kind of an automatic destruction routine.

Those are just guesses would love it if someone corrected me and clarified things for me.

Comment: If you're unsure, follow the simple rule: "Never use pointers; never use `new`." Once you understand the need for manually-managed object lifetime, you will know when to break this rule.

Comment: Uhm may I strongly urge you to open a book about C++.. variable scope, dynamic memory management are typically discussed in the 4th or 5th chapter of any C++ beginners books. @KerrekSB I wouldn't say that.. Especially in this case the uncertainity doesn't come from ambugity, but instead from not enough knowledge - if you are unsure make sure you read enough so you ARE sure.

Comment: Dynamically allocating memory is usually _slower_, and initialisation has nothing to do with any of this.

Comment: -1 this questions does not show any research effort, which would have been to look the subject up in a C++ book or similar

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The difference is in *storage duration*.

- Objects with *automatic storage duration* are your "normal" objects that automatically go out of scope at the end of the block in which they're defined.

  Create them like `int someInt`;

  You may have heard of them as "stack objects", though I *object* to this terminology.
- Objects with *dynamic storage duration* have something of a "manual" lifetime; you have to destroy them yourself with `delete`, and create them with the keyword `new`.

  You may have heard of them as "heap objects", though I object to this, too.

The use of pointers is actually not strictly relevant to either of them. You can have a pointer to an object of automatic storage duration (your second example), and you can have a pointer to an object of dynamic storage duration (your first example).

But it's rare that you'll want a pointer to an automatic object, because:

1. you don't have one "by default";
2. the object isn't going to last very long, so there's not a lot you can *do* with such a pointer.

By contrast, dynamic objects are often accessed through pointers, simply because the syntax comes close to enforcing it. `new` returns a pointer for you to use, you have to pass a pointer to `delete`, and (aside from using references) there's actually no other way to access the object. It lives "out there" in a cloud of dynamicness that's *not* sitting in the local scope.

Because of this, the usage of pointers is sometimes confused with the usage of dynamic storage, but in fact the former is not causally related to the latter.

Comment: Pointers to automatic variables can be useful when invoking a function that is supposed to mutate its arguments (and perhaps use its return value to indicate success).

Comment: @TamásSzelei: In this case you should use a reference.

Comment: @TamásSzelei: Well, true. That's very localised usage, though. I guess I'm talking about obtaining a pointer and storing it, not using a temporary in a single expression

Comment: @BjörnPollex you are right, for some reason I thought this was a C question (hence the use of malloc in my answer).

Answer (score 14):

An object created like this:

```
int foo;
```

has **automatic storage duration** - the object lives until the variable `foo` goes out of scope. This means that in your first example, `dynInt` will be an invalid pointer once `someInt` goes out of scope (for example, at the end of a function).

An object created like this:

```
int foo* = new int;
```

Has **dynamic storage duration** - the object lives until you explicitly call `delete` on it.

Initialization of the objects is an orthogonal concept; it is not directly related to which type of storage-duration you use. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1613341/what-do-the-following-phrases-mean-in-c-zero-default-and-value-initializat) for more information on initialization.

Comment: To be pedantic, you really don't know anything about the *memory*, because that depends on the implementation of your allocation function `::operator new()`. It's the *lifetime* of the object that is dynamic, i.e. manual: The *object* lives until you `delete` it. C++ separates memory allocation and object construction.

Comment: @KerrekSB: I am always a little scared when writing such an answer, because I am sure to get something wrong :)

Answer (score 5):

1. Your program gets an initial chunk of memory at startup. This memory is called the *stack*. The amount is usually around 2MB these days.
2. Your program can ask the OS for additional memory. This is called dynamic memory allocation. This allocates memory on the *free store* (C++ terminology) or the *heap* (C terminology). You can ask for as much memory as the system is willing to give (multiple gigabytes).

The syntax for allocating a variable on the stack looks like this:

```
{
    int a; // allocate on the stack
} // automatic cleanup on scope exit
```

The syntax for allocating a variable using memory from the free store looks like this:

```
int * a = new int; // ask OS memory for storing an int
delete a; // user is responsible for deleting the object
```

To answer your questions:

> When is one method preferred to the other.

1. Generally stack allocation is preferred.
2. Dynamic allocation required when you need to store a polymorphic object using its base type.
3. Always use smart pointer to automate deletion:

   - C++03: `boost::scoped_ptr`, `boost::shared_ptr` or `std::auto_ptr`.
   - C++11: `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`.

For example:

```
// stack allocation (safe)
Circle c; 

// heap allocation (unsafe)
Shape * shape = new Circle;
delete shape;

// heap allocation with smart pointers (safe)
std::unique_ptr<Shape> shape(new Circle);
```

> Further more why do I need to free up memory in the first case, but not in the second case.

As I mentioned above stack allocated variables are automatically deallocated on scope exit.
Note that you are not allowed to delete stack memory. Doing so would inevitably crash your application.

Comment: This answer is much better than the others because it actually explains which memory allocation to use in which situation

Answer (score 4):

For a single integer it only makes sense if you need the keep the value after for example, returning from a function. Had you declared `someInt` as you said, it would have been invalidated as soon as it went out of scope.

However, in general there is a greater use for dynamic allocation. There are many things that your program doesn't know before allocation and depends on input. For example, your program needs to read an image file. How big is that image file? We could say we store it in an array like this:

```
unsigned char data[1000000];
```

But that would only work if the image size was less than or equal to 1000000 bytes, and would also be wasteful for smaller images. Instead, we can dynamically allocate the memory:

```
unsigned char* data = new unsigned char[file_size];
```

Here, `file_size` is determined at runtime. You couldn't possibly tell this value at the time of compilation.

Comment: Couldn't you just do: "unsigned char data[file_size]; "?

Comment: No, you couldn't. Well, some C compilers might accept it, but that's still dynamic allocation and not standard C(89) nor C++; see [VLA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array). ISO C99 supports VLAs.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you are using `new` in C++ memory is allocated through `malloc` which calls the `sbrk` system call (or similar) itself. Therefore no one, except the OS, has knowledge about the requested size. So you'll have to use `delete` (which calls `free` which goes to `sbrk` again) for giving memory back to the system. Otherwise you'll get a memory leak.

Now, when it comes to your second case, the compiler has knowledge about the size of the allocated memory. That is, in your case, the size of one `int`. Setting a pointer to the address of this `int` does not change anything in the knowledge of the needed memory. Or with other words: The compiler is able to take care about freeing of the memory. In the first case with `new` this is not possible.

In addition to that: `new` respectively `malloc` do not need to allocate exactly the requsted size, which makes things a bit more complicated.

**Edit**

Two more common phrases: The first case is also known as static memory allocation (done by the compiler), the second case refers to dynamic memory allocation (done by the runtime system).

Answer (score 2):

Read more about [dynamic memory allocation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_memory_allocation#Dynamic_memory_allocation) and also [garbage collection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29)

You really need to **read a good C or C++ programming book**.

Explaining in detail would take a lot of time.

The heap is the memory inside which dynamic allocation (with `new` in C++ or `malloc` in C) happens. There are [system calls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) involved with growing and shrinking the heap. On Linux, they are [mmap & munmap](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap) (used to implement `malloc` and `new` etc...).

You can call a lot of times the allocation primitive. So you could put `int *p = new int;` inside a loop, and get a fresh location every time you loop!

Don't forget to release memory (with `delete` in C++ or `free` in C). Otherwise, you'll get a [memory leak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak) -a naughty kind of bug-. On Linux, [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) helps to catch them.

Answer (score 1):

What happens if your program is supposed to let the user store any number of integers? Then you'll need to decide during run-time, based on the user's input, how many ints to allocate, so this must be done dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell, dynamically allocated object's **lifetime is controlled by you** and not by the language. This allows you to let it live as long as it is required (as opposed to end of the scope), possibly determined by a condition that can only be calculated at run-rime.

Also, dynamic memory is typically much more "scalable" - i.e. you can allocate more and/or larger objects compared to stack-based allocation.

The allocation essentially "marks" a piece of memory so no other object can be allocated in the same space. De-allocation "unmarks" that piece of memory so it can be reused for later allocations. If you fail to deallocate memory after it is no longer needed, you get a condition known as "memory leak" - your program is occupying a memory it no longer needs, leading to possible failure to allocate new memory (due to the lack of free memory), and just generally putting an unnecessary strain on the system.