# where to place the pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers

what's the deffeence between using

(1) `HEAP num =* new HEAP`

(2) `HEAP *num = new HEAP`

in c++. Also when writing a method how would one return an object if the they use (2)?

Comment: Never use (1), it's equivalent to a simple `HEAP num;` *but* it also leaks memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++ symbols often change meaning depending on their context. In

```
HEAP num =* new HEAP
```

the `*` is the [dereference operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955198/what-does-dereferencing-a-pointer-mean). This gets the value of an object from a pointer. `*`

In

```
HEAP *num = new HEAP
```

`*` is not an operator, it is part of the type denoting that the variable is a pointer.

`*` is also used as the multiplication operator. Note that `*` can be overloaded to do anything the programmer wants it to do, but this should be reserved for multiplication-and-dereferencing-like behaviours to to prevent confusion.

## So what do these do?

```
HEAP num =* new HEAP
```

Copy constructs [Automatic variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_variable) `HEAP num`, which is a `HEAP`, with source `* new HEAP` where `* new HEAP` is a pointer to a [Dynamically allocated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8504070/c-dynamically-allocated-memory) `HEAP` that is promptly dereferenced with the `*` operator to get its value. Do not use this option because no pointer is kept to the dynamic allocation making it close to impossible to free. This is a memory leak.

```
HEAP *num = new HEAP
```

Initializes Automatically variable `HEAP *num`, which is a pointer to a `HEAP`, with a pointer to a Dynamically allocated `HEAP`. Avoid using this option because it requires the programmer to manually manage [the ownership](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49024982/what-is-ownership-of-resources-or-pointers) of the allocation by `delete`ing it exactly once at some point in the future. It is surprising how difficult such a simple-sounding thing can be to get right.

## Advice

Prefer

```
HEAP num;
```

which is an Automatic `HEAP` variable  so you do not have to worry about ownership or

```
std::unique_ptr<HEAP> num = std::make_unique<HEAP>();
```

which is an Automatic `std::unique_ptr<HEAP>` variable that holds a Dynamically allocated `HEAP` and manages the ownership for you. [Documentation for `std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr).

## How does one return (2)?

```
HEAP * getHeapPointer()
{
    HEAP * num = new HEAP;
    return num;
}
```

or simply,

```
HEAP * getHeapPointer()
{
    return new HEAP;
}
```