# C++ vector initialization?

Tags: c++, initialization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do the parentheses after the type name make a difference with new?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620137/do-the-parentheses-after-the-type-name-make-a-difference-with-new)
>   [What do the following phrases mean in C++: zero-, default- and value-initialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1613341/what-do-the-following-phrases-mean-in-c-zero-default-and-value-initializat)

I've used vector without any problem but i still have a question about it.
I always use code like this,

```
vector<int>* v1 = new vector<int>;
```

so, can i use:

```
vector<int>* v2 = new vector<int>();
```

I know what () does, but whats the difference? In v1, does vector ever initialize any integer?

Comment: Why are you using `new`?  What's wrong with `vector<int> v1;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First your question: new calls the default constructor, you don't need to do this "manually".
But then: Try to use value types as often as possible in C++. They are not only faster, but also easier and safer, because the destructor gets automaticly called when leaving the scope.
So just write

```
std::vector<int> v; // Calls default constructor
```

If you really need the heap, try using smart pointers such as shared_ptr and unique_ptr, this way you can't forget to call delete. (And delete also calls the destructor, no need to do this manually.)

Answer (score 0):

Both statements are the same. The constructor taking no parameters will be called in both cases.