# Will {0, 0} initialize array in the struct?

Tags: c++

In this code, will all 100 items of `C.B` be initialized to zero?

```
struct A { int B[100]; int D; };
A C = {0, 0};
```

It seems to work, but memory could have just been empty in advance.

Comment: This is not a duplicate, can you see the difference between initializing array and struct?

Comment: `A C = {0};` performs value initialization of an aggregate, hence it value-initializes each member. So indeed the member array is indeed zeroed.

Comment: @vsoftco, should it be {{0}} instead?

Comment: There are some rules (I cannot remember them from the top of my head) that say that you can elide the braces for aggregates. Here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization *"If the aggregate initialization uses the form with the equal sign (T a = {args..}), (until C++14) the braces around the nested initializer lists may be elided (omitted),..."*

Comment: Now that we see it this is indeed a interesting question! Is there a way to remove the dup flag from it?

Comment: By the way there's a answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11152160/initializing-a-struct-to-0 But I still think this question should be opened again.

Comment: So your case is a combination of the 2: aggregate initialization and value initialization.

Comment: @thelink2012: You are linking to question tagged for `C`. This question is tagged `C++` and uses `aggregate initialization` that is explained in the link by vsoftco. An array and a struct are both aggregates. Anyways in C++ you would use `A C = {};` or just `A C{};` from C++11.

Comment: @JesseGood Thus why I asked you guys to open the question again ;) The question is not a dup and is interesting.

Comment: @thelink2012: Well, the original question was changed, but anyways they all fall under `aggregate initialization`.

Answer (score 5):

The line

```
A C = {0, 0};
```

Performs [value initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) of the [aggregate](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) `A`. According to the standard, the braces can be omitted for aggregate initialization:

**8.5.1 Aggregates[dcl.init.aggr]/12**

> Braces can be elided in an initializer-list as follows. If the
>   initializer-list begins with a left brace, then the succeeding
>   comma-separated list of initializer-clauses initializes the members of
>   a subaggregate; it is erroneous for there to be more
>   initializer-clauses than members. If, however, the initializer-list
>   for a sub- aggregate does not begin with a left brace, then only
>   enough initializer-clauses from the list are taken to initialize the
>   members of the subaggregate; any remaining initializer-clauses are
>   left to initialize the next member of the aggregate of which the
>   current subaggregate is a member.
>
> [Example:
>
> ```
>  float y[4][3] = {
>    { 1, 3, 5 },
>    { 2, 4, 6 },
>    { 3, 5, 7 }, };
> ```
>
> is a completely-braced initialization: 1, 3, and 5 initialize the first row of the array y[0], namely y[0][0],
>   y[0][1], and y[0][2]. Likewise the next two lines initialize y[1] and
>   y[2]. The initializer ends early and therefore y[3]'s elements are
>   initialized as if explicitly initialized with an expression of the
>   form float(), that is, are initialized with 0.0. In the following
>   example, braces in the initializer-list are elided; however the
>   initializer-list has the same effect as the completely-braced
>   initializer-list of the above example,
>
> ```
>  float y[4][3] = {
>    1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6, 3, 5, 7 };
> ```
>
> The initializer for y begins with a left brace, but the one for y[0] does not, therefore three elements
>   from the list are used. Likewise the next three are taken successively
>   for y[1] and y[2]. — end example ]

Next

**8.5.1 Aggregates[dcl.init.aggr]/7**

> If there are fewer initializer-clauses in the list than there are
>   members in the aggregate, then each member not explicitly initialized
>   shall be initialized from its brace-or-equal-initializer or, if there
>   is no brace-or-equal- initializer, from an empty initializer list.

In your case, this mean that the first `0` is assigned to `B[0]` and the second `0` is assigned to `B[1]`. According then to **8.5.1/7**, the rest of the elements are value-initialized.

However, for clarity in this case, you should use `A C = {{0}, 0};`, or, better

```
A C{}; // or A C = {};
```

The only thing that worries me a bit is the g++ warning (`-Wextra`):

> warning: missing initializer for member 'main()::A::D'
>   [-Wmissing-field-initializers] A C {0,0};

But according to my interpretation of the standard above, you should be OK and `D` should have been initialized. I even tested it with some placement `new`, and the result is as expected

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    struct A { int B[100]; int D;};
    A memory{};
    memory.D = 42; 
    std::cout << memory.D << std::endl;

    // let's place something an A at the location of memory
    A* foo = new (&memory) A{0,0}; 
    // line below outputs 0, so D is erased; not the case if A* foo = new (&memory) A; 
    std::cout << memory.D << std::endl; // outputs 0
}
```

Comment: I already edited the question, so it is not {0} any more, but {0,0}. This way it makes my actual consideration more clear.