# C initilized global struct with uninitilized member ints defined beheviour?

Tags: c, c89

Uninitilized Global int are always 0 as per defined beheviour, this is not true if it is not global. What about Global structs?
Does

```
struct s
{
    int a;
}instance;

int main()
{    
    printf("%d\n", instance.a);
    return 0;
}
```

always print `0` or is it technically undefined beheviour?

Comment: Global (and static) variables are initialized with 0, yes. There's probably a duplicate.

Comment: Yes. Next question please ;)

Comment: It is not undefined behavior.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Initializing a struct to 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11152160/initializing-a-struct-to-0)

Comment: Global and static variables are alwaqys initialized with 0, regardless if it's `struct`s, arrays or simple variables (such as `char`, `int` etc.).

Comment: See 3rd answer of duplicate question link.

Comment: Thanks all! I read that thread before, but was unsure about the wording.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a global struct, all fields will be initialized to 0 / NULL.  This is detailed in section 6.7.9p10 of the current [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized
>   explicitly, its value is indeterminate. If an object that has static
>   or thread storage duration is not initialized explicitly, then:
>
> - if it has pointer type, it is initialized to a null pointer;
> - if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or unsigned) zero;
> - **if it is an aggregate, every member is initialized (recursively) according to these rules, and any padding is initialized to zero bits;**
> - if it is a union, the first named member is initialized (recursively) according to these rules, and any padding is initialized
>     to zero bits;

The old [C89 standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c89/c89-draft.html#3.5.7) has similar language in section 3.5.7:

> an object that has static storage duration is not initialized
>   explicitly, it is initialized implicitly as if every member that has
>   arithmetic type were assigned 0 and every member that has pointer type
>   were assigned a null pointer constant. If an object that has automatic
>   storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is
>   indeterminate
>
> ...
>
> If the aggregate contains members that are aggregates or unions, or if
>   the first member of a union is an aggregate or union, the rules apply
>   recursively to the subaggregates or contained unions

So in your case, `instance.a` is guaranteed to be set to 0.

Comment: Thanks! Your excerpt explains it perfectly.
I was a bit confused by the C99 passage often cited and CTRL+F through the C89 standard before to read __`If there are fewer initializers in a list than there are members of an aggregate, the remainder of the aggregate shall be initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration. `__ just to be confused by the language and C99's usage of "brace-enclosed list" in the equivalent passage.