# Char Array Initialization

Tags: c

How does this work::

```
char Test1[8] = {"abcde"} ;
```

AFAIK, this should be stored in memory at Test1 as

```
a b c d e 0 SomeJunkValue SomeJunkValue
```

instead it get stored as:

```
a b c d e 0 0 0
```

Initializing only adds one trailing NULL char after the string literals but how and why all other array members are initialized to **NULL** ?
Also, any links or any conceptual idea on what is the underlying method or function that does:`char TEST1[8] = {"abcde"} ;` would be very helpful.
How is:

```
char Test1[8] = {"abcde"} ;
```

different from

```
char Test1[8] = "abcde" ;
```

?

Comment: Related & Good Read: [C and C++ : Partial initialization of automatic structure](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10828294/452307)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unspecified members of a partially initialized aggregate are initialized to the zero of that type.

> #### 6.7.9 Initialization
>
> 21 - If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there are elements or members
>   of an aggregate, or fewer characters in a string literal used to initialize an array of known
>   size than there are elements in the array, the remainder of the aggregate shall be
>   initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration.
>
> 10 - [...] If an object that has static or thread storage duration is not initialized
>   explicitly, then:
>
> - if it has pointer type, it is initialized to a null pointer;
> - if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or unsigned) zero; [...]

For the array `char Test1[8]`, the initializers `{"abcde"}` and `"abcde"` are completely equivalent per 6.7.9:14:

> An array of character type may be initialized by a character string literal or UTF−8 string literal, optionally enclosed in braces.

Comment: @user1696837 it's up to the compiler.  The compiler can emit instructions to copy data from `.rodata`, to assign stack locations directly, to initialize in a loop either directly or by calling `memset`, or optimise out the stack object entirely if possible.