# C++ float array initialization

Tags: c++, arrays, floating-point, initialization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C and C++ : Partial initialization of automatic structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10828294/c-and-c-partial-initialization-of-automatic-structure)

While reading [Code Complete](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735619670), I came across an C++ array initialization example:

```
float studentGrades[ MAX_STUDENTS ] = { 0.0 };
```

I did not know C++ could initialize the entire array, so I've tested it:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    const int MAX_STUDENTS=4;
    float studentGrades[ MAX_STUDENTS ] = { 0.0 };
    for (int i=0; i<MAX_STUDENTS; i++) {
        cout << i << " " << studentGrades[i] << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The program gave the expected results:

```
0 0
1 0
2 0
3 0
```

But changing the initialization value from `0.0` to, say, `9.9`:

```
float studentGrades[ MAX_STUDENTS ] = { 9.9 };
```

Gave the interesting result:

```
0 9.9
1 0
2 0
3 0
```

Does the initialization declaration set only the first element in the array?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You only initialize the first N positions to the values in braces and all others are initialized to 0.  In this case, N is the number of arguments you passed to the initialization list, i.e.,

```
float arr1[10] = { };       // all elements are 0
float arr2[10] = { 0 };     // all elements are 0
float arr3[10] = { 1 };     // first element is 1, all others are 0
float arr4[10] = { 1, 2 };  // first element is 1, second is 2, all others are 0
```

Comment: Don't forget that you can use an empty initialization list, in which case *all* elements are set to zero.

Comment: You make it sound like 0 is a special case, but it's not. It's setting the first element to 0 and then the rest of them to 0.

Comment: @sftrabbit: Yep, it does sound that way doesn't it?  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

No, it sets all members/elements that haven't been explicitly set to their default-initialisation value, which is zero for numeric types.